# What's the most efficient test of whether a PHP string ends with another string?

Tags: php, string, performance

The standard PHP way to test whether a string `$str` ends with a substring `$test` is:

```
$endsWith = substr( $str, -strlen( $test ) ) == $test
```

Is this the fastest way?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->endsWith($test)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L117) or [`s($str)->endsWithIgnoreCase($test)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L131) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: PHP 8.0 introduces new method for this job `str_end_with`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/64160081/7082164

Answer (score 153, accepted):

What Assaf said is correct. There is a built in function in PHP to do exactly that.

```
substr_compare($str, $test, strlen($str)-strlen($test), strlen($test)) === 0;
```

If `$test` is longer than `$str` PHP will give a warning, so you need to check for that first.

```
function endswith($string, $test) {
    $strlen = strlen($string);
    $testlen = strlen($test);
    if ($testlen > $strlen) return false;
    return substr_compare($string, $test, $strlen - $testlen, $testlen) === 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice.  It does seem like comparing in-place would be faster than substr(), as Assaf pointed out.

Comment: mcrumley's answer is cool, but it should use '===' instead of '=='. '===' is more strict and usually does what you want, while '==' can lead to nasty surprises. mcrumley's third code snippet is correct, but the first two aren't. substr_compare() returns false in some error cases. In PHP, false == 0, so the code snippets would signal that the string has been found. With ===, this doesn't happen.

Comment: I ran into a bug today which will break the solution that you have given from PHP 5.5.11 and onwards. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67043

Comment: 3 function calls overhead doesn't make it fastest.

Answer (score 67):

This method is a tiny bit more memory-expensive, but it is faster:

```
stripos(strrev($haystack), $reversed_needle) === 0;
```

This is best when you know exactly what the needle is, so you can hard-code it reversed. If you reverse the needle programmatically, it becomes slower than the earlier method.

***Edit (12 years later)***: LOL, this is a super-old answer that I wrote when I didn't know what I was actually talking about. I'd like the think I've grown since then. @DavidHarkness is right, it is not very efficient in the negative case. Probably much faster to just iterate in reverse and bail early if you really need as much perf as possible. Also, php probably has better ways to do this now. Honestly, I haven't written php in nearly a decade, so I'll leave it up to others now.

Comment: -1 I seriously doubt this is faster, and it's tricky (cool but not usually helpful). If the haystack *doesn't* end with the needle, `stripos` will iterate the entire string in the worst case whereas `substr_compare` will compare at most the length of the needle. Yes, `substr_compare` requires calculating the length of the haystack (and much smaller needle), but this method requires that *and* copying it in full, and possibly converting the entire thing into lowercase to boot.

Comment: cool approach but inefficient (as mentioned in answer itself) in many cases! Still an upvote for being weirdly creative and demonstrating that there can always be more ways of doing same thing that you may ever imagine. Cheers!

Comment: I tested and find this method faster than the accepted answer. Even if both haystack and needle are reversed on the fly, it is faster.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Did you test to see if your doubts were warranted?

Comment: @Nathan No, it's not worth the time to benchmark since `substr_compare()` works nicely.

Comment: Very clever, but this is a two-liner I hope, with the first line commenting to the reader what it does :)

Answer (score 64):

```
$endsWith = substr_compare( $str, $test, -strlen( $test ) ) === 0
```

Negative offset "starts counting from the end of the string".

Comment: IMO it's one of the best from the provided solutions

Comment: +200 if I could. The key insight here is that using a negative length gets the end part of the string. You could also use substr with the -ve length and do an == against $test. The other answers are poor.

Answer (score 11):

Here’s a simple way to check whether one string ends with another, by giving `strpos` an offset right where the string should be found:

```
function stringEndsWith($whole, $end)
{
    return (strpos($whole, $end, strlen($whole) - strlen($end)) !== false);
}
```

Straightforward, and I think this’ll work in PHP 4.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on which sort of efficiency you care about.

Your version uses more memory due to the extra copy from the use of substr.

An alternative version might search the original string for the last occurrence of the substring without making a copy, but would probably be slower due to more testing.

Probably the most efficient way is to do loop char-by-char from the -sterlen(test) position till the end of the string and compare. That's the minimal amount of comparisons you can hope to do and there's hardly any extra memory used.

Answer (score 6):

In PHP 8:

```php
str_ends_with('haystack', 'stack'); // true
str_ends_with('haystack', 'K'); // false
```

and also:

```php
str_starts_with('haystack', 'hay'); // true
```

[PHP RFC: Add str_starts_with(), str_ends_with() and related functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/add_str_begin_and_end_functions)

Answer (score 5):

Another way would be to use the [`strrpos` function](http://docs.php.net/strrpos):

```
strrpos($str, $test) == strlen($str) - strlen($test)
```

But that’s not faster.

Answer (score 3):

I hope that the below answer may be efficient and also simple:

```
$content = "The main string to search";
$search = "search";
//For compare the begining string with case insensitive. 
if(stripos($content, $search) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';

//For compare the begining string with case sensitive. 
if(strpos($content, $search) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';

//For compare the ending string with case insensitive. 
if(stripos(strrev($content), strrev($search)) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';

//For compare the ending string with case sensitive. 
if(strpos(strrev($content), strrev($search)) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';
```

Comment: Don't you think that large $string values could cause some memory problems if they should be reversed, These approaches using `strrev`  do not look good to me in terms of efficienc

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is fast or not but for a single character test, these work, too:

```
(array_pop(str_split($string)) === $test) ? true : false;
($string[strlen($string)-1] === $test) ? true : false;
(strrev($string)[0] === $test) ? true : false;
```

Comment: Even if they do: don't you think that large `$string` values could cause some memory problems if they should be reversed, or split to an array first? These approaches do not look good to me in terms of efficiency

Answer (score 1):

easiest way to check it via regular expression

*for example* to check if the mail given is gmail:

```
echo (preg_match("/@gmail\.com$/","example-email@gmail.com"))?'true':'false';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the reverse functions like strrchr() would help you match the end of the string the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

This is pure PHP, without calling external functions, except for **strlen**.

```
function endsWith ($ends, $string)
{
    $strLength = strlen ($string);
    $endsLength = strlen ($ends);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $endsLength; $i++)
    {
        if ($string [$strLength - $i - 1] !== $ends [$i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for single-char needle:

```
if (@strrev($haystack)[0] == $needle) {
   // yes, it ends...
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it? Why use `strrev` instead of `substr($haystack, -1)`? Especially for long string, it could take some time to reverse it