# startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP

Tags: php, string

How can I write two functions that would take a string and return if it starts with the specified character/string or ends with it?

For example:

```
$str = '|apples}';

echo startsWith($str, '|'); //Returns true
echo endsWith($str, '}'); //Returns true
```

Comment: See Laravel's [Str class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php) startsWith() and endsWith() for [well-tested](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/tests/Support/SupportStrTest.php) methods. [Edge cases](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/a70c74d68c9ba922207246f225cccc64d5407911) had been encountered, so the widespread use of this code is an advantage.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->startsWith('|')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L69) and [`s($str)->endsWith('}')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L117) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: Warning: most answers here are unreliable in multi-byte encodings such as UTF-8.

Comment: Following up to my above comment, you may make sure to use the latest version (as of today, [5.4](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php)). Notably, startsWith() has been optimized for large haystack strings.

Comment: PHP 8.0 introduces new methods for this job `str_starts_with` and `str_end_with`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160081/7082164

Answer (score 1861, accepted):

### PHP 8.0 and higher

Since PHP 8.0 you can use:

[`str_starts_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with) and
[`str_ends_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with)

###### Example

```
var_dump(str_starts_with('|apples}', '|'));
var_dump(str_ends_with('|apples}', '}'));
```

### PHP before 8.0

```php
function startsWith( $haystack, $needle ) {
     $length = strlen( $needle );
     return substr( $haystack, 0, $length ) === $needle;
}
```

```php
function endsWith( $haystack, $needle ) {
    $length = strlen( $needle );
    if( !$length ) {
        return true;
    }
    return substr( $haystack, -$length ) === $needle;
}
```

Comment: variable names are unclear. eg, char is a string, not a single char. Perhaps consider rename params to conventional php $haystack and $needle.

Comment: Just FYI, the $length parameter in `endsWith()` is redundant, since `substr()` will terminate at the end of the string anyway.

Comment: I'd say endsWith('foo', '') == false is the correct behavior. Because foo doesn't end with nothing. 'Foo' ends with 'o', 'oo' and 'Foo'.

Comment: thank you, I found this notation more concise substr($haystack, - strlen($needle))
No need for $start and * -1

Comment: EndsWith can be written a lot shorter: `return substr($haystack, -strlen($needle))===$needle;`

Comment: startWith doesn't work with arguments ("100", "100"), changing equals to == solve issue

Comment: for startWith, strpos is faster than substr.

Comment: I was searching for a simple manner of testing is a string starts with any of a set of strings, something like strStartsWith(array(allStarts)). I posted what I did below, hoping someone could find it useful. I'm quite surprised PHP developers did not implement these functions, since they are very useful everyday.

Comment: Testing for `$haystack{0}===$needle{0}` before, speeds things up a bit if $needle and $haystack are not empty (see reply). If you are reusing the same $needle, save its length, no need to strlen() every time, add a $length parameter to startWith(...). Any information you have on the strings helps.

Comment: @RokKralj But only if `$needle` is not empty.

Comment: used it in my string class because its not using regex :-) https://github.com/bes89/string

Comment: You can avoid the `if` altogether by passing `$length` as the third parameter to `substr`: `return (substr($haystack, -$length, $length);`. This handles the case of `$length == 0` by returning an empty string and not the whole `$haystack`.

Comment: Hey @MrHus, do you mind if I use your functions in this post without attribution?

Comment: @D.Tate If I didn't want people to use it I would not have posted it to stackoverflow. So no attribution needed.

Comment: Much more readable than the other; this solution is easier to bugfix.

Comment: 5 lines of code, 5 suggestions of making it better. 500 lines of code, and everyone goes "meh, looks good to me"

Comment: @Loupax that is a good thing. People can comprehend 5 lines of code and reason about it. When it's 500 lines that's too much to comprehend. This is why you should write short functions.

Comment: @MrHus I would recommend using multi-byte safe functions, e.g. mb_strlen and mb_substr

Comment: By the way, what’s wrong with `$startsWith = strpos($str, '|') === 0; $endsWith = substr($str, -1) === '}';` ?

Comment: @RokKralj I disagree. All strings implicitly both start and end with the empty string. That is, the last 0 characters of the string matches the empty string, just like the first 0 characters does. Why handle n=0 differently than n=1,2,…?

Comment: The idea to handle empty strings separately is not a product of my brain. Watch out before you accuse someone.

Comment: @19Gerhard85 you don't need to worry about multi-bytes when comparing bytes to bytes. simple substr() and strlen() functions are ok for that.

Comment: @MrHus why not simply use strpos() in startsWith()?

Comment: @MikeShiyan: Nobody mentioned any bytes until now, it's all characters. When comparing bytes, "ü" != "ü" - one is "LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS", the other is "LATIN SMALL LETTER U" followed by "COMBINING DIAERESIS". Completely different bytes, different byte length (!), yet both are the same one *character*. Surely you have read https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @Piskvor so you're saying that the answer compares characters, not bytes? I think, that's not true - I suppose the `strlen()` and the `substr()` are binary-safe functions. As well as the `strpos()`. So I just don't understand, why the answer uses that code instead of simple `strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0`. 
P.S.: though I haven't read the mentioned article, I know the difference between characters and bytes, don't worry about that.

Comment: That's indeed true: the *question* is about characters, but the *answer* compares bytes.

Comment: At least for startWith() I don't get why this sneeky solution is needed. 1 million iterations take 1086ms, strncmp takes 1017ms with same result.

Comment: I think that "public static" should be added so that they can be used as a reference function without instantiating like if( SomeClassNAME::startsWith() )

Comment: the fact that there aren't native "starts with" and "ends with" functions maeks php silly.

Comment: adding strtoupper on the $haystack and $needle, with another parm for 'ignore case' would be helpful

Comment: This `startsWith()` function could be optimized by using [`strncmp()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php): `strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) === 0` (refs [PR 32243 in Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32243)). See also the "Common Userland Approaches" in this [PHP 8 RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/add_str_starts_with_and_ends_with_functions#downsides_of_common_userland_approaches) (pointed out in [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php/62169159#62169159)).

Comment: Just make sure to return `true` if the needle is en empty string.

Comment: I would suggest to check symfony php80 polyfills: https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-php80/blob/main/Php80.php#L96-L104

Answer (score 1106):

#### PHP < 8

You can use [`substr_compare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php) function to check start-with and ends-with:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr_compare($haystack, $needle, 0, strlen($needle)) === 0;
}
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr_compare($haystack, $needle, -strlen($needle)) === 0;
}
```

<sup>This should be one of the fastest solutions on PHP 7 ([benchmark script](https://gist.github.com/salmanarshad2000/99ce15b5be1bd12d7523939397eec20c)). Tested against 8KB haystacks, various length needles and full, partial and no match cases. `strncmp` is a touch faster for starts-with but it cannot check ends-with.</sup>

Comment: Please note that @DavidWallace and @FrancescoMM comments apply to an older version of this answer. The current answer uses `strrpos` which (should) fail immediately if needle does not match the beginning of haystack.

Comment: I don't get it. Based on http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php: "If the value is negative, search will instead start from that many characters from the end of the string, searching backwards." This seems to indicate that we're starting at character 0 (due to `-strlength($haystack)`) and searching *backward* from there? Doesn't that mean you're not searching anything? I also don't understand the `!== false` parts of this. I'm guessing this is relying on a quirk of PHP where some values are "truthy" and others "falsy" but how does that work in this case?

Comment: @Welbog: for example haystack = `xxxyyy` needle = `yyy` and using `strrpos` the search starts from the first `x`. Now we do not have a successful match here (found x instead of y) and we cannot go backward anymore (we're at start of string) the search fails *immediately*. About using `!== false` -- `strrpos` in the above example will return 0 or false and not other value. Likewise, `strpos` in the above example can return `$temp` (the expected position) or false. I went with `!== false` for consistency but you could use `=== 0` and `=== $temp` in the functions respectively.

Comment: So much unnecessary work on this.  Why not use strpos === 0 for the startsWith. Down voted for drastically over complicating suboptimal coding response.

Comment: @spoo it has already been established that strpos === 0 is a terrible solution if haystack is large and needle does not exist.

Comment: @hanshenrik: _"substr_compare — Binary safe comparison"_, and Unicode supports binary representation, see https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms . So both substr_compare() and str_starts_with() are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 261):

Updated 23-Aug-2016

## Functions

```
function substr_startswith($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) === $needle;
}

function preg_match_startswith($haystack, $needle) {
    return preg_match('~' . preg_quote($needle, '~') . '~A', $haystack) > 0;
}

function substr_compare_startswith($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr_compare($haystack, $needle, 0, strlen($needle)) === 0;
}

function strpos_startswith($haystack, $needle) {
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}

function strncmp_startswith($haystack, $needle) {
    return strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) === 0;
}

function strncmp_startswith2($haystack, $needle) {
    return $haystack[0] === $needle[0]
        ? strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) === 0
        : false;
}
```

## Tests

```
echo 'generating tests';
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    if($i % 2500 === 0) echo '.';
    $test_cases[] = [
        random_bytes(random_int(1, 7000)),
        random_bytes(random_int(1, 3000)),
    ];
}
echo "done!\n";


$functions = ['substr_startswith', 'preg_match_startswith', 'substr_compare_startswith', 'strpos_startswith', 'strncmp_startswith', 'strncmp_startswith2'];
$results = [];

foreach($functions as $func) {
    $start = microtime(true);
    foreach($test_cases as $tc) {
        $func(...$tc);
    }
    $results[$func] = (microtime(true) - $start) * 1000;
}

asort($results);

foreach($results as $func => $time) {
    echo "$func: " . number_format($time, 1) . " ms\n";
}
```

## Results (PHP 7.0.9)

(Sorted fastest to slowest)

```
strncmp_startswith2: 40.2 ms
strncmp_startswith: 42.9 ms
substr_compare_startswith: 44.5 ms
substr_startswith: 48.4 ms
strpos_startswith: 138.7 ms
preg_match_startswith: 13,152.4 ms
```

## Results (PHP 5.3.29)

(Sorted fastest to slowest)

```
strncmp_startswith2: 477.9 ms
strpos_startswith: 522.1 ms
strncmp_startswith: 617.1 ms
substr_compare_startswith: 706.7 ms
substr_startswith: 756.8 ms
preg_match_startswith: 10,200.0 ms
```

[startswith_benchmark.php](https://gist.github.com/mnpenner/9a941ab830a457ed0358#file-startswith_benchmark-php)

Comment: If the strings are not empty, as in your tests, this is actually somehow (20-30%) faster: `function startswith5b($haystack, $needle) {return ($haystack{0}==$needle{0})?strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) === 0:FALSE;}` I added a reply below.

Comment: @FrancescoMM I've incorporated your version into my tests. That does not appear to be true; at least not when the first letter has a 1 in 64 chance of being a match.

Comment: strange, it may depend on the PHP implementation as I had tested it on your same set, anyway thanks for adding it

Comment: why did you say that substr_startswith is the fastest when substr_compare_startswith only has 133?

Comment: @Jronny Because 110 is less than 133...??

Comment: Darn, I don't know what went to my head that time. Prolly the lack of sleep.

Comment: This is what I got on the same set on OsX MAMP environment on 10000 loops, to confirm it depends on the setup.

`generating tests..........done!
substr_startswith: 51.8469810486 ms
preg_match_startswith: 1991.78195 ms
substr_compare_startswith: 53.2069206238 ms
strpos_startswith: 63.8959407806 ms
strncmp_startswith: 45.2649593353 ms
strncmp_startswith2: 42.7808761597 ms` so.. do some testing on you production machine!

Comment: Another repro, on a 2015 Macbook Pro (Core i5) with php 5.6.20. Loops = 20000:
generating tests....................done!
substr_startswith: 39.290904998779 ms 
preg_match_startswith: 1911.6959571838 ms 
substr_compare_startswith: 37.993907928467 ms 
strpos_startswith: 51.711082458496 ms 
strncmp_startswith: 42.64497756958 ms 
strncmp_startswith2: 42.857885360718 ms

Comment: Updated for PHP 7. `strncmp_startswith2` moved from 4th place to 1st. Most functions got significantly faster, except preg_match which is now twice as slow.

Comment: @mpen any chance of showing us your preferred endsWith() alternatives as well ?

Comment: @AdamJones I didn't come up with any alternatives. Here's what I'm using now: https://gist.github.com/mnpenner/1e35f9f20d0982c541c6ea1fd45ff5a8

Comment: preg_quote() is a very slow function. with - preg_match_startswith: **2,240.1** ms; without - preg_match_startswith: **258.0** ms

Comment: Use `return preg_match('~\Q' . $needle . '\E~A', $haystack) > 0;`

Comment: @Visman You'd still have to double the backslashes in the needle if you used `\Q...\E` no? Edit: Or I guess *just* `\E` you'd have to escape... actually I don't know *how* to escape a literal `\E`. Edit2: I guess you could `str_replace('\\E', '\\E\\\\E\\Q', $needle)` which is even uglier than preg_quote. Not sure if it'd be faster or not.

Comment: @mpen, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d54ac02d3ccd5317f82677dcf6600c1c27ed78b - working, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2e57ac68f2f52ca5af68f27be26aff39df72283f - does not work. Probably a bug. https://regex101.com/r/kFBxWR/1 - the emulator is working properly.

Comment: @Visman Yeah...but I asked about putting a literal `\E` in the search string, not just a start/end delim.

Comment: @mpen, I noticed not the elephant at all :(

Comment: These tests are no good in testing the performance. What you are doing is using random string as the needle. In 99.99% cases there will be NO match. Most of the functions will exit after matching first byte. What about cases when a match is found? Which function takes least amount of time to conclude successful match? What about cases where 99% of needle match but not the last few bytes? Which function takes least amount of time to conclude no match?

Comment: @SalmanA You raise some good points. Not sure I want to redesign the test cases right now though.

Comment: `$haystack[0]` will throw a notice error if you don't test it with isset. The same for needles. But if you add tests, it will slow down its performance

Comment: What about `endsWith`?

Comment: @mbomb007 Try these: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php#125913

Answer (score 147):

All answers so far seem to do loads of unnecessary work, `strlen calculations`, `string allocations (substr)`, etc. The `'strpos'` and `'stripos'` functions return the index of the first occurrence of `$needle` in `$haystack`:

```
function startsWith($haystack,$needle,$case=true)
{
    if ($case)
        return strpos($haystack, $needle, 0) === 0;

    return stripos($haystack, $needle, 0) === 0;
}

function endsWith($haystack,$needle,$case=true)
{
    $expectedPosition = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle);

    if ($case)
        return strrpos($haystack, $needle, 0) === $expectedPosition;

    return strripos($haystack, $needle, 0) === $expectedPosition;
}
```

Comment: `endsWith()` function has an error.
Its first line should be (without the -1):

  `$expectedPosition = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle);`

Comment: The strlen() thing is not unnecessary. In case the string doesn't start with the given needle then ur code will unnecessarily scan the whole haystack.

Comment: you think scanning the entire string is cheaper than checking just the beginning? i don't think strpos is any cheaper.

Comment: @Mark yea, checking just the beginning is a LOT faster, especially if you're doing something like checking MIME types (or any other place where the string is bound to be large)

Comment: @mark I did some benchmarks with 1000 char haystack and 10 or 800 char needle and strpos was 30% faster. Do your benchmarks before stating that something is faster or not...

Comment: @wdev: did your string always contain the needle? `strpos` would be slowest when the string doesn't even contain the needle (has to scan the whole thing). and what are you comparing against exactly? using substr, or other methods? `substr` has to allocate a new string, there's a substantial cost in that too.

Comment: @Mark Match, no match and same string comparison: https://gist.github.com/3268655

Comment: @wdev: Not a fair comparison. Two of your 3 tests have the needle start at the beginning, which is where strpos excels at. Run it just for "no match" and `strncmp` wins. I don't know why strpos would ever win though. Perhaps because `strncmp` is doing a full comparison, and not just equal/not-equal. And btw, I did do some benches if you had looked further down this thread; but regardless, I'm entitled to speculate.

Comment: You should strongly consider quoting the needle like `strpos($haystack, "$needle", 0)` if there's _any_ chance it's not already a string (e.g., if it's coming from `json_decode()`). Otherwise, the [odd] default behavior of `strpos()` may cause unexpected results: "[If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.](http://php.net/strpos)"

Comment: Please don't use this example, you risk falling onto large performance problems.

Comment: return strpos($haystack, $needle, $expectedPosition) === $expectedPosition; should be better in that it doesn't scan the whole string when failing. Though then you will need an `if ($expectedPosition < 0) return false;` check in case the needle's length is greater than the haystack's.

Comment: this. I really wonder why this is not the accepted `startsWith()` function.

Comment: This returns false for `startsWith('abc', '')` You got to check for empty string first.

Comment: 3rd arguments to all str*pos() functions are unnecessary. They default to "0".

Answer (score 55):

## PHP 8 update

PHP 8 includes new [`str_starts_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php) and [`str_ends_with`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php) functions that finally provide a performant and convenient solution to this problem:

```
$str = "beginningMiddleEnd";
if (str_starts_with($str, "beg")) echo "printed\n";
if (str_starts_with($str, "Beg")) echo "not printed\n";
if (str_ends_with($str, "End")) echo "printed\n";
if (str_ends_with($str, "end")) echo "not printed\n";
```

The [RFC for this feature](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/add_str_starts_with_and_ends_with_functions) provides more information, and also a discussion of the merits and problems of obvious (and not-so-obvious) userland implementations.

Answer (score 54):

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle, $case = true) {
    if ($case) {
        return (strcmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
    }
    return (strcasecmp(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle, $case = true) {
    if ($case) {
        return (strcmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
    }
    return (strcasecmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)), $needle) === 0);
}
```

**Credit To**:

[Check if a string ends with another string](http://snipplr.com/view/13213/check-if-a-string-ends-with-another-string/)

[Check if a string begins with another string](http://snipplr.com/view/13214/check-if-a-string-begins-with-another-string/)

Comment: strtolower is not the best way to make case insensitive functions. In some locales casing is more complex than just upper and lower.

Comment: I see complaining and no solution... If you're gonna say it's bad, then you should give an example of how it should be as well.

Comment: @WebDevHobo: that's why I added an answer myself a day before your comment. For your code strcasecmp was indeed the right thing to do.

Answer (score 48):

This question already has many answers, but in some cases you can settle for something simpler than all of them.
If the string you're looking for is known (hardcoded), you can use regular expressions without any quoting etc.

Check if a string starts with 'ABC':

```
preg_match('/^ABC/', $myString); // "^" here means beginning of string
```

ends with 'ABC':

```
preg_match('/ABC$/', $myString); // "$" here means end of string
```

In my simple case, I wanted to check if a string ends with slash:

```
preg_match('#/$#', $myPath);   // Use "#" as delimiter instead of escaping slash
```

The advantage: since it's very short and simple, you don't have to define a function (such as `endsWith()`) as shown above.

But again -- this is not a solution for every case, just this very specific one.

Comment: you don't need to hard code the string. the regex _can_ be dynamic.

Comment: @self true, but if the string is not hardcoded, you have to escape it. Currently there are 2 answers on this question that do it. This is easy, but it complicates the code just a bit. So my point was that for very simple cases, where hardcoding is possible, you can keep it simple.

Answer (score 39):

The regex functions above, but with the other tweaks also suggested above:

```
 function startsWith($needle, $haystack) {
     return preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '/', $haystack);
 }

 function endsWith($needle, $haystack) {
     return preg_match('/' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '$/', $haystack);
 }
```

Comment: in php for string operations the ordering of parameters is $haystack, $needle. these functions are backwards and act like array functions where the ordering is actually $needle, $haystack.

Answer (score 33):

#### Fastest endsWith() solution:

```
# Checks if a string ends in a string
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr($haystack,-strlen($needle))===$needle;
}
```

#### Benchmark:

```
# This answer
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    return substr($haystack,-strlen($needle))===$needle;
}

# Accepted answer
function endsWith2($haystack, $needle) {
    $length = strlen($needle);

    return $length === 0 ||
    (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}

# Second most-voted answer
function endsWith3($haystack, $needle) {
    // search forward starting from end minus needle length characters
    if ($needle === '') {
        return true;
    }
    $diff = \strlen($haystack) - \strlen($needle);
    return $diff >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $diff) !== false;
}

# Regex answer
function endsWith4($haystack, $needle) {
    return preg_match('/' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '$/', $haystack);
}

function timedebug() {
    $test = 10000000;

    $time1 = microtime(true);
    for ($i=0; $i < $test; $i++) {
        $tmp = endsWith('TestShortcode', 'Shortcode');
    }
    $time2 = microtime(true);
    $result1 = $time2 - $time1;

    for ($i=0; $i < $test; $i++) {
        $tmp = endsWith2('TestShortcode', 'Shortcode');
    }
    $time3 = microtime(true);
    $result2 = $time3 - $time2;

    for ($i=0; $i < $test; $i++) {
        $tmp = endsWith3('TestShortcode', 'Shortcode');
    }
    $time4 = microtime(true);
    $result3 = $time4 - $time3;

    for ($i=0; $i < $test; $i++) {
        $tmp = endsWith4('TestShortcode', 'Shortcode');
    }
    $time5 = microtime(true);
    $result4 = $time5 - $time4;

    echo $test.'x endsWith: '.$result1.' seconds # This answer<br>';
    echo $test.'x endsWith2: '.$result4.' seconds # Accepted answer<br>';
    echo $test.'x endsWith3: '.$result2.' seconds # Second most voted answer<br>';
    echo $test.'x endsWith4: '.$result3.' seconds # Regex answer<br>';
    exit;
}
timedebug();
```

#### Benchmark Results:

```
10000000x endsWith: 1.5760900974274 seconds # This answer
10000000x endsWith2: 3.7102129459381 seconds # Accepted answer
10000000x endsWith3: 1.8731069564819 seconds # Second most voted answer
10000000x endsWith4: 2.1521229743958 seconds # Regex answer
```

Comment: +1 for taking time to compare different solutions and actually benchmark them! you should also mention what version of PHP you used, as optimisations are done as the language evolves! I've seen dramatic improvements on string comparison functions from one PHP version to another :)

Comment: echoing @ChristopheDeliens and his request to provide the PHP version. I ran your test on 7.3.2 and got similar results FWIW.

Answer (score 29):

If speed is important for you, try this.(I believe it is the fastest method)

Works only for strings and if $haystack is only 1 character

```
function startsWithChar($needle, $haystack)
{
   return ($needle === $haystack[0]);
}

function endsWithChar($needle, $haystack)
{
   return ($needle === $haystack[strlen($haystack) - 1]);
}

$str='|apples}';
echo startsWithChar('|',$str); //Returns true
echo endsWithChar('}',$str); //Returns true
echo startsWithChar('=',$str); //Returns false
echo endsWithChar('#',$str); //Returns false
```

Comment: this is probably the most efficient answer because not using any function as extra, just usual string...

Comment: It should likely check if string has at least one character and has the two parameter swapped

Comment: Creative.  Needles which contain haystacks.  BTW there is some ugly waning with: `endsWithChar('','x')`, but the result is correct

Comment: I like your answer, but it's quite funny,... the needle and haystack are the other way around :) ... i.e. you would search for a Needle in a Haystack, therefore, it should be:      return ($needle === $haystack[0]); , but nice answer, thanks!

Comment: @HeiderSati: Great observation! That is what @Tino was talking about `Creative. Needles which contain haystacks.`... I didn't pay enough attention. Thanks! I fixed it. :)

Answer (score 23):

Here are two functions that don't introduce a temporary string, which could be useful when needles are substantially big:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) === 0;
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === '' || substr_compare($haystack, $needle, -strlen($needle)) === 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Works since PHP5.1 and IMHO best answer.  But `endsWidth` should do `return $needle==='' || substr_compare(`... so it works as expected for `-strlen($needle)===0` which, without the fix, makes `endsWith('a','')` return `false`

Comment: @Tino Thanks ... I feel that's a bug in `substr_compare()` actually, so I've added a [PR](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/599) to fix that :)

Comment: The call `endsWith('', 'foo')` triggers a Warning: “substr_compare(): The start position cannot exceed initial string length”. Maybe that's another bug in `substr_compare()`, but to avoid it, you need a pre-check like ...`|| (strlen($needle) <= strlen($haystack) && substr_compare(`...`) === 0);`

Comment: @gx_ No need to slowdown with more code.  Just use `return $needle === '' || @substr_compare(`.. to suppress this warning.

Answer (score 19):

I realize this has been finished, but you may want to look at [strncmp](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php) as it allows you to put the length of the string to compare against, so:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle, $case=true) {
    if ($case)
        return strncasecmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) == 0;
    else
        return strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) == 0;
}
```

Comment: how would you do endswith with this?

Comment: @Mark - you can look at the accepted answer, but I prefer to use strncmp mainly because I think it is safer.

Comment: I mean with strncmp specifically. You can't specify an offset. That would mean your endsWith function would have to use a different method entirely.

Comment: @Mark - For endsWith I would just use strrpos (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), but, generally, anytime you go to use strcmp strncmp is probably a safer option.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a multi-byte safe version of the accepted answer, it works fine for UTF-8 strings:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    $length = mb_strlen($needle, 'UTF-8');
    return (mb_substr($haystack, 0, $length, 'UTF-8') === $needle);
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    $length = mb_strlen($needle, 'UTF-8');
    return $length === 0 ||
        (mb_substr($haystack, -$length, $length, 'UTF-8') === $needle);
}
```

Comment: im pretty sure this is just a waste of CPU. all you need to check, for StarstWith and EndsWith, is just checking that the bytes match, and that's exactly what the accepted answer is doing. this 1 wastes time calculating the number of utf8 characters of the needle, and where the position of the n'th utf8 character of the haystack is.. i think, without being 100% certain, this is just a waste of cpu. can you come up with an actual test case where the accepted answer fails, and this doesn't?

Comment: @hanshenrik - it could happen btw, in the very rare case when you look for a string that contains the same bytes as an UTF8 but with half of the last character missing. Like, you have unicode C5 91 (letter "ő") and you look for C5 (letter "Å") it shouldn't give you a match. On the other hand, sure, why would you search an utf haystack for a non-utf needle... But for bulletproof checks, this must be considered a possibility.

Comment: In `startsWith` it should be `$length = mb_strlen($needle, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @ThomasKekeisen Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: The accepted (well, currently accepted) solution is already multibyte-safe. It's actually binary-safe, which is an even stronger guarantee.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [**`strpos`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [**`strrpos`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)

```
$bStartsWith = strpos($sHaystack, $sNeedle) == 0;
$bEndsWith = strrpos($sHaystack, $sNeedle) == strlen($sHaystack)-strlen($sNeedle);
```

Comment: Should you be using triple equals here `strpos($sHaystack, $sNeedle) == 0` like this `strpos($sHaystack, $sNeedle) === 0`? I see a bug, when `false == 0` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 10):

Focusing on startswith, if you are sure strings are not empty, adding a test on the first char, before the comparison, the strlen, etc., speeds things up a bit:

```
function startswith5b($haystack, $needle) {
    return ($haystack{0}==$needle{0})?strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) === 0:FALSE;
}
```

It is somehow (20%-30%) faster. Adding another char test, like $haystack{1}===$needle{1} does not seem to speedup things much, may even slow down.

`===` seems faster than `==`
Conditional operator `(a)?b:c` seems faster than `if(a) b; else c;`

---

**For those asking "why not use strpos?" calling other solutions "unnecessary work"**

---

strpos is fast, but it is not the right tool for this job.

To understand, here is a little simulation as an example:

```
Search a12345678c inside bcdefga12345678xbbbbb.....bbbbba12345678c
```

**What the computer does "inside"?**

```
    With strccmp, etc...

    is a===b? NO
    return false



    With strpos

    is a===b? NO -- iterating in haysack
    is a===c? NO
    is a===d? NO
    ....
    is a===g? NO
    is a===g? NO
    is a===a? YES
    is 1===1? YES -- iterating in needle
    is 2===3? YES
    is 4===4? YES
    ....
    is 8===8? YES
    is c===x? NO: oh God,
    is a===1? NO -- iterating in haysack again
    is a===2? NO
    is a===3? NO
    is a===4? NO
    ....
    is a===x? NO
    is a===b? NO
    is a===b? NO
    is a===b? NO
    is a===b? NO
    is a===b? NO
    is a===b? NO
    is a===b? NO
    ...
    ... may many times...
    ...
    is a===b? NO
    is a===a? YES -- iterating in needle again
    is 1===1? YES
    is 2===3? YES
    is 4===4? YES
    is 8===8? YES
    is c===c? YES YES YES I have found the same string! yay!
    was it at position 0? NOPE
    What you mean NO? So the string I found is useless? YEs.
    Damn.
    return false
```

Assuming strlen does not iterate the whole string (but even in that case) this is not convenient at all.

Comment: There's only a speed up if the first characters are different.

Comment: @Jack yes, of course, the idea is that statistically that happens, so the speedup is generrally a 20%-30% over the whole test set (including cases where it is not different). You gain a lot when they are different and loose very little when they are not. In the average you gain that 30% (varies depending on set, but mostly you gain speed on large tests)

Comment: **"but it is not the right tool for this job"**... Any citation?

Comment: WTF. I listed all the process below whom should I cite, more than that? Would you use a function that searches till the end of a string to tell you that the fist character is not an 'a'? Do it who cares?  It's not the right tool because it is a tool for searching, not for comparing, there is no need to cite Aristoteles to state the obvious!

Answer (score 9):

Short and easy-to-understand one-liners without regular expressions.

startsWith() is straight forward.

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
   return (strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0);
}
```

endsWith() uses the slightly fancy and slow strrev():

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
   return (strpos(strrev($haystack), strrev($needle)) === 0);
}
```

Comment: @FrancescoMM: **strpos is not the "right tool"**... Why? What are the "right tools" then?  ***EDIT:*** I read your answer below. I thought programming is like invention using the resources you have.. So there's no right or wrong... only working or not working... performance is secondary.

Comment: "because it is a tool for searching, not for comparing?" Cit. Aristoteles

Answer (score 8):

in short:

```
function startsWith($str, $needle){
   return substr($str, 0, strlen($needle)) === $needle;
}

function endsWith($str, $needle){
   $length = strlen($needle);
   return !$length || substr($str, - $length) === $needle;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I hope that the below answer may be efficient and also simple:

```
$content = "The main string to search";
$search = "T";
//For compare the begining string with case insensitive. 
if(stripos($content, $search) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';

//For compare the begining string with case sensitive. 
if(strpos($content, $search) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';

//For compare the ending string with case insensitive. 
if(stripos(strrev($content), strrev($search)) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';

//For compare the ending string with case sensitive. 
if(strpos(strrev($content), strrev($search)) === 0) echo 'Yes';
else echo 'No';
```

Answer (score 8):

I usually end up going with a library like [underscore-php](http://anahkiasen.github.io/underscore-php/#String-endsWith) these days.

```php
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); //use if needed
use Underscore\Types\String; 

$str = "there is a string";
echo( String::startsWith($str, 'the') ); // 1
echo( String::endsWith($str, 'ring')); // 1
```

The library is full of other handy functions.

Answer (score 8):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7168986/3404298) by [mpen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65387/mpen) is incredibly thorough, but, unfortunately, the provided benchmark has a very important and detrimental oversight.

Because every byte in needles and haystacks is completely random, the probability that a needle-haystack pair will differ on the very first byte is 99.609375%, which means that, on average, about 99609 of the 100000 pairs will differ on the very first byte. In other words, the benchmark is heavily biased towards `startswith` implementations which check the first byte explicitly, as `strncmp_startswith2` does.

If the test-generating loop is instead implemented as follows:

```
echo 'generating tests';
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    if($i % 2500 === 0) echo '.';

    $haystack_length = random_int(1, 7000);
    $haystack = random_bytes($haystack_length);

    $needle_length = random_int(1, 3000);
    $overlap_length = min(random_int(0, $needle_length), $haystack_length);
    $needle = ($needle_length > $overlap_length) ?
        substr($haystack, 0, $overlap_length) . random_bytes($needle_length - $overlap_length) :
        substr($haystack, 0, $needle_length);

    $test_cases[] = [$haystack, $needle];
}
echo " done!<br />";
```

the benchmark results tell a slightly different story:

```
strncmp_startswith: 223.0 ms
substr_startswith: 228.0 ms
substr_compare_startswith: 238.0 ms
strncmp_startswith2: 253.0 ms
strpos_startswith: 349.0 ms
preg_match_startswith: 20,828.7 ms
```

Of course, this benchmark may still not be perfectly unbiased, but it tests the efficiency of the algorithms when given partially matching needles as well.

Answer (score 7):

#### Do it faster:

```
function startsWith($haystack,$needle) {
    if($needle==="") return true;
    if($haystack[0]<>$needle[0]) return false; // ------------------------- speed boost!
    return (0===substr_compare($haystack,$needle,0,strlen($needle)));
}
```

That extra line, comparing the first character of the strings, can make the
false case return *immediately*, therefore making many of your comparisons
a lot faster (7x faster when I measured).  In the true case you pay virtually no price in performance for that single line so I think it's worth including.  (Also, in practice, when you test many strings for a specific starting chunk, most comparisons will fail since in a typical case you're looking for something.)

*NOTE: the bug in @Tino's comment below has aleady been fixed*

#### As for strings vs integers

If you want to force string comparison (that is, you expect startsWith("1234",12) to be true), you'll need some typecasting:

```php
function startsWith($haystack,$needle) {
    if($needle==="") return true;
    $haystack = (string)$haystack;
    $needle   = (string)$needle;
    if($haystack[0]<>$needle[0]) return false; // ------------------------- speed boost!
    return (0===substr_compare($haystack,$needle,0,strlen($needle)));
}
```

I don't think it's necessary but it's an interesting edge case, leading to questions like "does boolean true begin with a t?" - so you decide, but make sure you decide for good.

Comment: Bug in your code: `startsWith("123", "0")` gives `true`

Comment: Yup, bad !$checking happened. Sorry!  (Just wanted to illustrate the concept in line 3)

Comment: @Tino I'd say we could remove these 2 comments now, wouldn't you agree? I mean, point taken, it's fixed and it's been 2 years.

Answer (score 5):

This may work

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
     return substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) == $needle;
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419658

Answer (score 4):

The `substr` function can return `false` in many special cases, so here is my version, which deals with these issues:

```
function startsWith( $haystack, $needle ){
  return $needle === ''.substr( $haystack, 0, strlen( $needle )); // substr's false => empty string
}

function endsWith( $haystack, $needle ){
  $len = strlen( $needle );
  return $needle === ''.substr( $haystack, -$len, $len ); // ! len=0
}
```

Tests (`true` means good):

```
var_dump( startsWith('',''));
var_dump( startsWith('1',''));
var_dump(!startsWith('','1'));
var_dump( startsWith('1','1'));
var_dump( startsWith('1234','12'));
var_dump(!startsWith('1234','34'));
var_dump(!startsWith('12','1234'));
var_dump(!startsWith('34','1234'));
var_dump('---');
var_dump( endsWith('',''));
var_dump( endsWith('1',''));
var_dump(!endsWith('','1'));
var_dump( endsWith('1','1'));
var_dump(!endsWith('1234','12'));
var_dump( endsWith('1234','34'));
var_dump(!endsWith('12','1234'));
var_dump(!endsWith('34','1234'));
```

Also, the `substr_compare` function also worth looking.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php

Answer (score 4):

Why not the following?

```
//How to check if a string begins with another string
$haystack = "valuehaystack";
$needle = "value";
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0){
    echo "Found " . $needle . " at the beginning of " . $haystack . "!";
}
```

Output:

> Found value at the beginning of valuehaystack!

Keep in mind, `strpos` will return false if the needle was not found in the haystack, and will return 0 if, and only if, needle was found at index 0 (AKA the beginning).

And here's endsWith:

```
$haystack = "valuehaystack";
$needle = "haystack";

//If index of the needle plus the length of the needle is the same length as the entire haystack.
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) + strlen($needle) === strlen($haystack)){
    echo "Found " . $needle . " at the end of " . $haystack . "!";
}
```

In this scenario there is no need for a function startsWith() as

```
(strpos($stringToSearch, $doesItStartWithThis) === 0)
```

will return true or false accurately.

It seems odd it's this simple with all the wild functions running rampant here.

Comment: Seems odd that if you are searching for "xy" inside string "abcdefghijklmxyz" instead of just comparing "x" to "a" and returning FALSE, you look every character from "a" to "m" then end up finding "xy" inside the string, and at last you return FALSE because the position of it is not zero! This is what you are doing, and it is odd and wilder than any other rampant function here.

Comment: The simplicity is in the typing, not the logic.

Comment: It's not so much the logic, it's the possible optimization that Francsco was pointing out. Using `strpos()` will be slow except when it does match. `strncmp()` would be much better in this case.

Comment: When you're doing such low level functions, you typically want to go for the most speed-optimized solution, no matter how complex, as this will be called millions of times. Every microsecond you gain or lose here will make a very real difference. So better tweak the hell out of it (and then forget about the complexity, now that you have the function), instead of going for the looks and lose horrifying amount of time later when you don't even know what's gone wrong. Imagine checking a 2GB string that doesn't match.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this

```
     function startWith($haystack,$needle){
              if(substr($haystack,0, strlen($needle))===$needle)
              return true;
        }

  function endWith($haystack,$needle){
              if(substr($haystack, -strlen($needle))===$needle)
              return true;
        }
```

Comment: Forgetting to return false if it doesn't match. Errgo incorrect as is the return value of a function should not be 'assumed', but I know what you're going after at least compared to other answers.

Answer (score 3):

Based on James Black's answer, here is its endsWith version:

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle, $case=true) {
    if ($case)
        return strncmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) == 0;
    else
        return strncasecmp($haystack, $needle, strlen($needle)) == 0;
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle, $case=true) {
     return startsWith(strrev($haystack),strrev($needle),$case);

}
```

Note: I have swapped the if-else part for James Black's startsWith function, because strncasecmp is actually the case-insensitive version of strncmp.

Comment: Note that the `strrev()` is *creative* but very costly, especially if you have strings of say... 100Kb.

Comment: Use `===` instead of `==` to be sure. `0` is equal to a lot of things in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the previous answers will work just as well. However, this is possibly as short as you can make it and have it do what you desire. You just state that you'd like it to 'return true'. So I've included solutions that returns boolean true/false and the textual true/false.

```
// boolean true/false
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return stripos($haystack, $needle) === 0 ? 1 : 0;
}


// textual true/false
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0 ? 'true' : 'false';
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return stripos($haystack, $needle) === 0 ? 'true' : 'false';
}
```

Comment: True. However, Peter was asking for a function that would work with character strings. Nonetheless, I've updated my answer to appease you.

Comment: After the edit your solution now is completely obsolete.  It returns `'true'` and `'false'` as strings, which are both `true` in a boolean sense.  It's a good pattern for something like http://underhanded.xcott.com/ though ;)

Comment: Well, Peter just stated he wanted it to return 'true'. So I figured I'd return what he asked for. I've added both versions, just in case that isn't what he wanted.

Answer (score 3):

No-copy and no-intern-loop:

```
function startsWith(string $string, string $start): bool
{
    return strrpos($string, $start, - strlen($string)) !== false;
}

function endsWith(string $string, string $end): bool
{
    return ($offset = strlen($string) - strlen($end)) >= 0 
    && strpos($string, $end, $offset) !== false;
}
```

Comment: this should be much faster than MrHus's implementation! i might benchmark it

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an efficient solution for PHP 4. You could get faster results if on PHP 5 by using `substr_compare` instead of `strcasecmp(substr(...))`.

```
function stringBeginsWith($haystack, $beginning, $caseInsensitivity = false)
{
    if ($caseInsensitivity)
        return strncasecmp($haystack, $beginning, strlen($beginning)) === 0;
    else
        return strncmp($haystack, $beginning, strlen($beginning)) === 0;
}

function stringEndsWith($haystack, $ending, $caseInsensitivity = false)
{
    if ($caseInsensitivity)
        return strcasecmp(substr($haystack, strlen($haystack) - strlen($ending)), $haystack) === 0;
    else
        return strpos($haystack, $ending, strlen($haystack) - strlen($ending)) !== false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use regular expressions:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle, $case=true) {
  return preg_match("/.*{$needle}$/" . (($case) ? "" : "i"), $haystack);
}
```

Comment: $needle should be escaped with `preg_quote($needle, '/')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fnmatch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) function for this.

```
// Starts with.
fnmatch('prefix*', $haystack);
// Ends with.
fnmatch('*suffix', $haystack);
```

Comment: warning, not binary safe, and not even safe against needles containing wildcards =/

Answer (score 0):

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    $length = mb_strlen($needle);
    return mb_substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle;
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    $length = mb_strlen($needle);
    if(!$length)
    {
     return true;
    }
    
    return mb_substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle;
}
```

String length and character positioning are two examples where multi-byte vs single-byte can play a difference. Standard strings in PHP are char arrays just as in C, which are always single byte. so the third character in a string (`str[2]`) by normal strlen would actually be the start of the second character if UTF-16. If looking for `{` at the beginning of a string to see if a string could be JSON this wouldn't be a huge deal since `{` is a valid single byte character such as in ASCII encoding, but if checking the end of a string for the emogi  vs  to judge reactions it's a different story since they are multipbyte characters.

Answer (score 0):

I had the task of creating the most approximate polyfill of **str_starts_with()** for the open CMS EffCore and the result was the following code:

```
namespace {
    if (!function_exists('str_starts_with')) {
        function str_starts_with($haystack, $needle) {
            if (is_null    ($haystack)) trigger_error('str_starts_with(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in '.__FILE__, E_USER_DEPRECATED);
            if (is_null    ($needle)  ) trigger_error('str_starts_with(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($needle) of type string is deprecated in '.__FILE__, E_USER_DEPRECATED);
            if (is_array   ($haystack)) throw new TypeError('str_starts_with(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, array given');
            if (is_object  ($haystack)) throw new TypeError('str_starts_with(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, object given');
            if (is_resource($haystack)) throw new TypeError('str_starts_with(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, resource given');
            if (is_array   ($needle)  ) throw new TypeError('str_starts_with(): Argument #2 ($needle) must be of type string, array given');
            if (is_object  ($needle)  ) throw new TypeError('str_starts_with(): Argument #2 ($needle) must be of type string, object given');
            if (is_resource($needle)  ) throw new TypeError('str_starts_with(): Argument #2 ($needle) must be of type string, resource given');
            if ((string)$needle === '') return true;
            return strpos((string)$haystack, (string)$needle) === 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Test data:

```
str_starts_with('100', '')               # true
str_starts_with('100', '1')              # true
str_starts_with('100', '0')              # false
str_starts_with('100', 0)                # false
str_starts_with('100', 1)                # true
str_starts_with('100', 0.0)              # false
str_starts_with('100', 1.0)              # true
str_starts_with('100', true)             # true / (string)true  === '1'
str_starts_with('100', false)            # true / (string)false === ''
str_starts_with('100', null)             # Warning
str_starts_with('100', [])               # Exception
str_starts_with('100', [0])              # Exception
str_starts_with('100', [1])              # Exception
str_starts_with('100', new stdCLass)     # Exception
str_starts_with('100', new SomeClass)    # Exception
str_starts_with('100', fopen('resource') # Exception

str_starts_with('010', '')               # true
str_starts_with('010', '1')              # false
str_starts_with('010', '0')              # true
str_starts_with('010', 0)                # true
str_starts_with('010', 1)                # false
str_starts_with('010', 0.0)              # true
str_starts_with('010', 1.0)              # false
str_starts_with('010', true)             # false / (string)true  === '1'
str_starts_with('010', false)            # true  / (string)false === ''
str_starts_with('010', null)             # Warning
str_starts_with('010', [])               # Exception
str_starts_with('010', [0])              # Exception
str_starts_with('010', [1])              # Exception
str_starts_with('010', new stdCLass)     # Exception
str_starts_with('010', new SomeClass)    # Exception
str_starts_with('010', fopen('resource') # Exception


str_starts_with('',                  '1') # false
str_starts_with('100',               '1') # true
str_starts_with('010',               '1') # false
str_starts_with('001',               '1') # false
str_starts_with(0,                   '1') # false
str_starts_with(1,                   '1') # true
str_starts_with(0.0,                 '1') # false
str_starts_with(1.0,                 '1') # true
str_starts_with(true,                '1') # true  / (string)true  === '1'
str_starts_with(false,               '1') # false / (string)false === ''
str_starts_with(null,                '1') # Warning
str_starts_with([],                  '1') # Exception
str_starts_with([0],                 '1') # Exception
str_starts_with([1],                 '1') # Exception
str_starts_with(new stdCLass,        '1') # Exception
str_starts_with(new SomeClass,       '1') # Exception
str_starts_with(fofopen('resource'), '1') # Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm really late to the party, but I had to use `PHP 7` and made it work with `explode`, which looks really simple:

```php
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
  $cutsQuantity = 2;
  $parts = explode($needle, $haystack, $cutsQuantity);
  return ($parts[0] === '');
}

function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
  $parts = explode($needle, $haystack);
  return (array_pop($parts) === '');
}

var_dump(startsWith('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'The quick')); // true
var_dump(startsWith('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'lazy dog')); // false
var_dump(endsWith('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'The quick')); // false
var_dump(endsWith('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', 'lazy dog')); // true
```

According to `3v4l.org` this should work from `PHP 4.3.0`: https://3v4l.org/gRggY#v4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Let me give a 2024 answer to this that I think still brings value.

I created a polyfill based on Symfony code that I think better that most of the stuff posted here.

```php
<?php
/**
 * These are based on symfony/polyfill-php80. The aim of this is to have a minimalistic polyfill
 * for only the str_* functions of PHP 8.0. Requires php 7.1 or higher.
 *
 * @link https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-php80/blob/1.x/bootstrap.php
 * @link https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-php80/blob/1.x/Php80.php
 *
 * @license GPL-3.0
 * @copyright (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>, (c) 2024 Nicolas Jonas nextgenthemes.com
 *
 * @author Ion Bazan <ion.bazan@gmail.com>
 * @author Nico Oelgart <nicoswd@gmail.com>
 * @author Nicolas Grekas <p@tchwork.com>
 * @author Nicolas Jonas nextgenthemes.com
 */

// < PHP 7.1
if ( \PHP_VERSION_ID < 70100 ) {
    exit( 'The str_contains, str_starts_with and str_ends_with polyfills require PHP 7.1 or higher.' );
}

// >= PHP 8.0
if ( \PHP_VERSION_ID >= 80000 ) {
    return;
}

if ( ! function_exists('str_contains') ) {
    function str_contains( ?string $haystack, ?string $needle ): bool {

        $haystack = $haystack ?? '';
        $needle   = $needle ?? '';

        return '' === $needle || false !== strpos($haystack, $needle);
    }
}
if ( ! function_exists('str_starts_with') ) {
    function str_starts_with( ?string $haystack, ?string $needle ): bool {

        $haystack = $haystack ?? '';
        $needle   = $needle ?? '';

        return 0 === strncmp($haystack, $needle, \strlen($needle));
    }
}
if ( ! function_exists('str_ends_with') ) {
    function str_ends_with( ?string $haystack, ?string $needle ): bool {

        $haystack = $haystack ?? '';
        $needle   = $needle ?? '';

        if ( '' === $needle || $needle === $haystack ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( '' === $haystack ) {
            return false;
        }

        $needle_length = \strlen($needle);

        return $needle_length <= \strlen($haystack) && 0 === substr_compare($haystack, $needle, -$needle_length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ends_with = strrchr($text, '.'); // Ends with dot
$start_with = (0 === strpos($text, '.')); // Starts with dot
```

Comment: According to the docs, strrchr() will return the string from the last occurrence of '.' until the end, meaning your $ends_with would be true if '.' is __anywhere__ in $text. Therefore ends_with should be: **('.' === strrchr($text, '.'))**

Comment: As your answer is wrong and does not do what it claims, and you refuse to accept my edit to fix your answer, I'm downvoting this answer as it is "dangerously incorrect".

Answer (score -1):

### Laravel 9.0

If you are using Laravel then you can do the following (if you are not using Laravel, you really should be).

```
Str::of('a long string')->startsWith('a');
Str::of('a long string')->endsWith('string');

//true
//true
```