# How to check if a string starts with "_" in PHP?

Tags: php

Example: I have a `$variable = "_foo"`, and I want to make absolutely sure that $variable does not start with an underscore `"_"`. How can I do that in PHP? Is there some access to the char array behind the string?

Comment: Someone had posted an answer that used a regular expression which surprisingly got downvoted 4 times on the grounds that it was "not an appropriate use of regular expressions". The owner of that answer deleted it due to peer pressure. If input validation is not a good use of regular expressions, I don't know what is. Performance is **not** a significant factor in this use case. If the poster would like to undelete the regular expression answer, I will happily upvote it.

Comment: @Asaph: Regular expressions are over-used, and over-suggested. They are _completely_ over-kill for this use case. I don't see how you can claim that performance is not a significant factor; you certainly don't back it up.

Comment: I'm afraid I agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit here, a regex is an overkill, contrived answer to someone who doesn't know PHP basics. I think the regex answerer just went, "Oops!" :)

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson Both regex and non-regex solutions are valid; any performance concerns should be added as a caveat in the body or pointed out in the comments. The OP isn't the only one who benefits from their question; the reader is left to decide which solution to go with.

Comment: @rath Any overcomplicated answer that doesn't have side effects or straight up bugs is valid, doesn't mean it's a good answer. Especially since the OP also asked about the char array.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson You make a valid point. Cheers

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You might check out the `substr` function in php and grab the first character that way:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
if (substr('_abcdef', 0, 1) === '_') { ... }
```

Comment: PHP 8.0 implements new method `str_starts_with` so it would be now `str_starts_with('_abcdef', '_')`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php/64160081#64160081

Answer (score 141):

```
$variable[0] != "_"
```

#### How does it work?

In PHP you can get particular character of a string with array index notation. `$variable[0]` is the first character of a string (if $variable is a string).

Comment: An explanation as to why this works would be awesome, but +1 anyway.

Comment: There you go. Added explanation for you.

Comment: You should test if the string is at least one byte long before accessing the first byte.

Comment: skipping the test works for me on PHP 5.3.0

Comment: Amazing how people will think of substr and strpos BEFORE thinking of this...

Comment: amazing how people will ask for explanation instead of consulting the manual.

Comment: @Carson Myers: Accessing non-existing bytes causes an *uninitialized string offset* notice.

Comment: This works for a single character, but i thought `substr` was a more generic solution that would work for multiple characters and I thought regex would be a step too far. That's not too say I didn't think of this... It's programming 101.

Comment: Python already has this kind of syntax for accessing sub-strings since long ago.

Comment: @dusoft: That's not uncommon, unfortunately.

Comment: For the single character case requested:

    $starts_with_underscore = (is_string($variable) && $variable!='' && $variable[0]=='_');

would check its a string and there are characters there before accessing element 0.

If you can guarantee you know it is a string first, you could drop the first test.

Comment: upvote for genius teaching me something new today :)

Comment: Whaaaaat?! Why is this not more common knowledge? The dev next to me has never heard of this either.

Comment: This no longer works (tested in PHP 7.4), use `substr` instead (see accepted answer by @AlexSexton)

Comment: I have tested it on PHP 8.1 and it works fine. For more than one character, PHP 8 includes the `str_starts_with` function.

Answer (score 57):

**Update**: as of PHP8, you can use

- [`str_starts_with` — Checks if a string starts with a given substring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-starts-with.php)

Example from Manual:

```
<?php
if (str_starts_with('abc', '')) {
    echo "All strings start with the empty string";
}
?>
```

---

**Original answer from 2009:**

Since someone mentioned efficiency, I've benchmarked the functions given so far out of curiosity:

```
function startsWith1($str, $char) {
    return strpos($str, $char) === 0;
}
function startsWith2($str, $char) {
    return stripos($str, $char) === 0;
}
function startsWith3($str, $char) {
    return substr($str, 0, 1) === $char;
}
function startsWith4($str, $char){
    return $str[0] === $char;
}
function startsWith5($str, $char){
    return (bool) preg_match('/^' . $char . '/', $str);
}
function startsWith6($str, $char) {
    if (is_null($encoding)) $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
    return mb_substr($str, 0, mb_strlen($char, $encoding), $encoding) === $char;
}
```

Here are the results on my average DualCore machine with 100.000 runs each

```
// Testing '_string'
startsWith1 took 0.385906934738
startsWith2 took 0.457293987274
startsWith3 took 0.412894964218
startsWith4 took 0.366240024567 <-- fastest
startsWith5 took 0.642996072769
startsWith6 took 1.39859509468

// Tested "string"
startsWith1 took 0.384965896606
startsWith2 took 0.445554971695
startsWith3 took 0.42377281189
startsWith4 took 0.373164176941 <-- fastest
startsWith5 took 0.630424022675
startsWith6 took 1.40699005127

// Tested 1000 char random string [a-z0-9]
startsWith1 took 0.430691003799
startsWith2 took 4.447286129
startsWith3 took 0.413349866867
startsWith4 took 0.368592977524 <-- fastest
startsWith5 took 0.627470016479
startsWith6 took 1.40957403183

// Tested 1000 char random string [a-z0-9] with '_' prefix
startsWith1 took 0.384054899216
startsWith2 took 4.41522812843
startsWith3 took 0.408898115158
startsWith4 took 0.363884925842 <-- fastest
startsWith5 took 0.638479948044
startsWith6 took 1.41304707527
```

As you can see, treating the haystack as array to find out the char at the first position is *always the fastest* solution. It is also always performing at equal speed, regardless of string length. Using `strpos` is faster than `substr` for short strings but slower for long strings, when the string does not start with the prefix. The difference is irrelevant though. `stripos` is *incredibly* slow with long strings. `preg_match` performs mostly the same regardless of string length, but is only mediocre in speed. The `mb_substr` solution performs worst, while probably being more reliable though.

Given that these numbers are for 100.000 runs, it should be obvious that we are talking about 0.0000x seconds per call. Picking one over the other for *efficiency* is a worthless micro-optimization, unless your app is doing `startsWith` checking for a living.

Comment: +1: I'm actually surprised that `preg_match` is so fast, frankly.

Comment: I love performance tests and results. +1.

Comment: +1 for thinking to run benchmarks, but the last paragraph probably should be emphasised a little more - for 99% of those coming across this answer these benchmarks are only useful as a point of curiosity. As a point of curiosity, it's also been almost 15 years since these benchmarks, so it would be interesting to see what the results look like with PHP 8's `str_starts_with`.

Answer (score 10):

This is the most simple answer where you are not concerned about performance:

```
if (strpos($string, '_') === 0) {
    # code
}
```

If strpos returns `0` it means that what you were looking for begins at character `0`, the start of the string.

It is documented thoroughly here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

(PS `$string[0] === '_'` is the best answer)

Answer (score 6):

```
function starts_with($s, $prefix){
    // returns a bool
    return strpos($s, $prefix) === 0;
}

starts_with($variable, "_");
```

Comment: +1 All other solutions barf on empty string input.

Comment: Inefficient - scans the whole string if the prefix is not found immediately.

Comment: From the `substr` manual: "If string is less than or equal to start characters long, FALSE will be returned." So substr($foo,0,1) works perfectly with empty strings.

Comment: As Seva said, this is really too inefficient. If I had to use a function I would go with substr instead of strpos

Comment: @Wim: Thanks for pointing that out. Yet another example of PHP featuring an unintuitive, yet convenient behavior.

Comment: `if($s==="") return false;
else use_other_solution();`
That means other solutions can be made empty string-proof too.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s a better *starts with* function:

```
function mb_startsWith($str, $prefix, $encoding=null) {
    if (is_null($encoding)) $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
    return mb_substr($str, 0, mb_strlen($prefix, $encoding), $encoding) === $prefix;
}
```

Comment: what problem does this piece of overengineering solve?

Comment: he's trying to check for underscores, not accents.

Comment: @just somebody: It allows to test for arbitrary prefixes while taking multibyte strings into account.

Answer (score 2):

To build on pinusnegra's answer, and in response to Gumbo's comment on that answer:

```
function has_leading_underscore($string) {

    return $string[0] === '_';

}
```

Running on PHP 5.3.0, the following works and returns the expected value, even without checking if the string is at least 1 character in length:

```
echo has_leading_underscore('_somestring').', ';
echo has_leading_underscore('somestring').', ';
echo has_leading_underscore('').', ';
echo has_leading_underscore(null).', ';
echo has_leading_underscore(false).', ';
echo has_leading_underscore(0).', ';
echo has_leading_underscore(array('_foo', 'bar'));

/*
 * output: true, false, false, false, false, false, false
 */
```

I don't know how other versions of PHP will react, but if they all work, then this method is probably more efficient than the substr route.

Comment: why are you using the strings 'yes'/'no'? The language has booleans.

Comment: @Chad I can't remember. If I had to guess it'd be because I was directly printing the result and I felt like reading yes/no instead of true/false for some reason. You're right that using booleans would be better, and additionally it would simplify the logic. I'll change it.