# compare portion of the string using php

Tags: php, regex

I want to check whether the search keyword 'cli' or 'ent' or 'cl' word exists in the string 'client' and case insensitive. I used the preg_match function with the pattern '\bclient\b'. but it is not showing the correct result. Match not found error getting.

Please anyone help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use regular expressions for this, it's extra overhead and complexity where a regular string function would suffice.  Why not go with [stripos()](http://php.net/stripos) instead?

```
$str = 'client';
$terms = array('cli','ent','cl');
foreach($terms as $t) {
    if (stripos($str,$t) !== false) {
        echo "$t exists in $str";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `strpos()/stripos()` are faster and more memory efficient than `strstr()/stristr()` if you just need to know whether a given substring exists.

Comment: echo stripos('client',$filterstr); it is showing 0 as result. when my search keyword ='cli'

Comment: Yes.  If you read the documentation for `stripos()` you'll see that if returns the position index of the substring match, not the substring itself.  If you want to output which term matched, just `echo $filterstring`.  You didn't mention what kind of output you wanted in your function, just that you wanted to match a substring, so I assumed you were just looking for a true/false match.

Comment: Thanks for ur help and quick reply. I got the results using that function. Thanks again.

$pos1 = stripos("client", $filterstr);
if ($pos1 !== false)
$flag=1;
return $flag;

Comment: I agree, but `stripos` as oppsed to `strpos` gets slower the longer the strings become up to the extent where Regex *may* be faster. See a similar question and my benchmarks at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962031/how-to-check-if-a-string-starts-with-in-php/1962244#1962244

Answer (score 0):

Try the pattern `/cli?|ent/`

Explanation:

cli matches the first part. The i? makes the i optional in the search.

`|` means or, and that matches `cli`, or `ent`.

Answer (score 0):

`\b` is word boundary, It would not match `cli` in `client`, you need to remove `\b`