# string has prefix PHP

Tags: php, objective-c, string, if-statement, prefix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP startsWith() and endsWith() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions)
>   [Check if variable starts with ‘http’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419644/check-if-variable-starts-with-http)

How make an if-statement that if $mystring has the prefix "http://" then {do something}.

I've done this in objective-c like this:

```
if([mynsstring hasPrefix:@"http://"])
{
//Do something...
}
```

I don't know how to do this in PHP.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/strings - in PHP the string library is a list of functions, that might be different from string objects in objective C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest would be using [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to compare

```
if (substr($mystring, 0, 7) === 'http://') {
     // do something
}
```

Remember of course to take the exact number of characters.