# Skipping a word that starts with # in PHP

Tags: php, html, web

I have the following list of words (`myfile.txt`) which I want to display 
using PHP:

```
 word1
 #word2
 word3
```

What I want to do is to skip those lines that start with # above.

Below is the PHP code I used to display the words.
But I don't know how to skip the # word.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('myfile.txt','r');

if($fp){
  while(!feof($fp)){
    $name = fgets($fp);
    $name = rtrim($name);
    $value = urlencode($name);
    if(strlen($name) > 0){
      echo "<option value=$value>$name</option>";
    }
  }
 }
?>
</select>
</td>
```

What's the way to achieve that?

Comment: `if($name[0] == '#')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by extending the condition to:

```
if((strlen($name) > 0) && ($name[0] != '#')){
```

Take a look at php [manual on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) - section *String access and modification by character*.

If you ever needed checking more complex strings (like `//` or `--`) you may implement your own [`startsWith($haystack, $needle)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473026/1149736) function or use:

- `substr($name, 0, 2) == '//'`
- `strpos($name, '//') == 0`

Answer (score 2):

```
...
$name = fgets($fp);
$name = rtrim($name);
$value = urlencode($name);

if( strpos($value, '#') === 0 ) { continue; }
else // your code with if (strlen ...)
```

For more info, read also this article: [Check if variable starts with 'http'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419644/check-if-variable-starts-with-http)

Answer (score 1):

you can check with [substr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
if (substr($value,0,1)=="#"){
// do nothing
}
```

hope this will sure help u.

Answer (score 1):

Use following

```
$fp = fopen('myfile.txt','r');

if($fp){
  while(!feof($fp)){
    $name = fgets($fp);
    $name = rtrim($name);
    $value = urlencode($name);
    if(strlen($name) > 0 && $name[0]!='#'){
      echo "<option value=$value>$name</option>";
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as below:

```
$f = file("myfile.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($f as $l) {
    if (strpos($l, '#') === 0)
        continue;
    $line = htmlspecialchars($l);
    echo "<option value=\"" . addslashes($line) . "\">$line</option>\n";
}
```