# Is there a period in the string?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match

So i am using this wordpress function to get the users image

```
the_author_meta('author_image', the_author_ID()
```

and it will either return `something.jpg` or `something.png` or `something.gif` if it finds an image otherwise it will return an integer like 2330. How would i do a preg_match or some conditional to let me know if an image is present. I was thinking of doing a preg_match to see if there is a period in the name but if someone has a better idea that would be great..

Comment: It seems that you're storing two different things in the author_image usermeta.  Perhaps that should be fixed?  Unless that's on purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpler:

```
if (is_numeric($author_image)){
  // this is presumably not a file
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is check the extension of the file to see if it ends with something (ex. '.jpg', '.png', etc.) you can use the solution presented here:

[startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions)

I do not have familiarity with the library that you are using, but there really should be a better way to detect if the file is actually an image (some sort of meta data). Maybe reading the documentation will help?

EDIT: I misread the part about the function returning integers if an image is not found. The `is_numeric()` solution is probably enough, but I'll leave my answer up to give you options (for example, if you want to distinguish between image types).