# How to match rows in array to an array of masks?

Tags: php, arrays, search, partial-matches

I have array like this:

`array('1224*', '543*', '321*' ...)` which contains about 17,00 "masks" or prefixes.

I have a second array:

`array('123456789', '123456788', '987654321' ....)` which contain about 250,000 numbers.

Now, how can I efficiently match every number from the second array using the array of masks/prefixes?

**[EDIT]**

The first array contains only prefixes and every entry has only one `*` at the end.

Comment: Perhaps using a trie could work well in this situation.

Comment: @mfonda my english isn't so good, I can't understand what can/should I use?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: 17k masks, 250k numbers. In arrays? Wouldn't you be better of handling this in a different language than PHP, or even in a database? I can't imagine PHP will do this quickly, however you do it.

Comment: How large is the largest mask (in chars). How large is the largest number (in chars)?. Do you need all results at once? And: What have you tried so far and into which concrete problems did you run?

Comment: the largest mask have 6 chars (without the `*`) and all numbers are 9 chars long

Comment: @BerryLangerak doing this just in a "hardcore" two `for` loops takes 3 seconds, on my laptop, and this will be used on a high-end server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's a solution:

Prelimary steps:

1. Sort array 1, cutting off the `*`'s.

Searching:

1. For each number in array 2 do

   1. Find the first and last entry in array 1 of which the first character matches that of `number` (binary search).
   2. Do the same for the second character, this time searching not the whole array but between `first` and `last` (binary search).
   3. Repeat 2 for the nth character until a string is found.

This should be `O(k*n*log(n))` where `n` is the average number length (in digits) and `k` the number of numbers.

---

Basically this is a 1 dimensional [Radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree), for optimal performance you should implement it, but it can be quite hard.

Comment: Binary search might be a very good idea indead :) but will it handle situations that masks can be from 2, to 6 chars long? (test numbers are always 9 char long)

Comment: @canni: Yes, assuming that the shortest match is always the best and that the wildcard always comes last (so `123*` but not `12*34`).

Comment: masks are always end with `*` maybe I wrote this wrong, array 1 contains only prefixes, and those prefixes are always unique ie. there is no overlapping (when `123*` => no prefix `1234*`)

Answer (score 2):

My two cents....

```
$s = array('1234*', '543*', '321*');
$f = array('123456789', '123456788', '987654321');

foreach ($f as $haystack) {
    echo $haystack."<br>";
    foreach ($s as $needle) {
        $needle = str_replace("*","",$needle);
        echo $haystack "- ".$needle.": ".startsWith($haystack, $needle)."<br>";
    }
}

function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    $length = strlen($needle);
    return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}
```

To improve performance it might be a good idea to sort both arrays first and to add an exit clause in the inner `foreach` loop.

By the way, the `startWith`-function is from this great solution in SO: [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions)

Comment: This is a nice initial implementation, but `startsWith` will become way too slow, turning this into a `O(k*n*n)` algorithm.

Comment: I totally agree with you. There are obviously alot of ways to optimize this, and several different approaches for this kind of problem. I just wanted to show a basic approach for the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would to be use preg_grep in a loop:

```
$masks = array('1224*', '543*', '321*' ...);
$data = array('123456789', '123456788', '987654321' ....);

$matches = array();
foreach($masks as $mask) {
    $mask = substr($mask, 0, strlen($masks) - 2); // strip off trailing *
    $matches[$mask] = preg_grep("/^$mask/", $data);
}
```

No idea how efficient this would be, just offering it up as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Although regex is not famous for being *fast*, I'd like to know how well `preg_grep()` can perform if the pattern is boiled down to its leanest form and only called once (not in a loop).

By removing longer masks which are covered by shorter masks, the pattern will be greatly reduced.  How much will the reduction be? of course, I cannot say for sure, but with 17,000 masks, there are sure to be a fair amount of redundancy.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uLOKf))

```
$masks = ['1224*', '543*', '321*', '12245*', '5*', '122488*'];
sort($masks);
$needle = rtrim(array_shift($masks), '*');
$keep[] = $needle;
foreach ($masks as $mask) {
    if (strpos($mask, $needle) !== 0) {
        $needle = rtrim($mask, '*');
        $keep[] = $needle;
    }
}
// now $keep only contains: ['1224', '321', '5']

$numbers = ['122456789', '123456788', '321876543234567', '55555555555555555', '987654321'];

var_export(
    preg_grep('~^(?:' . implode('|', $keep) . ')~', $numbers)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '122456789',
  2 => '321876543234567',
  3 => '55555555555555555',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the PHP function array_intersect_key.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question