# Simple PHP Regex String Starts With

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for the regex to stet if a string starts with another string. This has to be RegEx and it has to be PHP regex.

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions

Comment: Not really related. Question specifically asks for a "regex" solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$result = preg_match("#^startText(.*)$#i", $string);
if($result == 0)
{
    echo "No match";
}
else
{
    echo "Match found.";
}
```

[PHP.net Regular Expressions](http://au.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

`preg_match` returns either `0` for no matches found, or `1`, because `preg_match` stops at the first match. If you want to count all matches, use `preg_match_all`.

Check the PHP website if you have more trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to use regex to find a sub-string of a string?.. but here ya go...

```
/^(?=test).*$/
```

**Usage**

```
<?php

    $string_to_find = 'some_string';
    $search_string = 'some_string_that is longer';

    $regex = '/^(?='.$string_to_find.').*$/';

    // $result variable will be boolean (true|false)
    $result = preg_match($regex, $search_string );
```

**Alternatively**

```
<?php
    function check(){ 
        if(strpos('some_string', 'some_string_that is longer') == 0){ return true; } else { return false; }
    }
```

Regex **Explained** Below:

```
^                   //anchor start matching to first letter

(?=.....)           //look ahead - match exact string value


.*                  //match any leftover characters 0 to infinity x's

$                   //anchor at end of string
```