# How to List the Files from a Custom Folder in Wordpress?

Tags: linux, wordpress, file, ubuntu

I am new to Wordpress, and need some help.

What I am trying to do is that I have created a Wordpress account, and now I want to create a section in that blog which consists all my files which are uploaded on my computer on a specific folder. So whenever I change any file there, it changes over there automatically. Is this possible?

Also is there a way that I can give only read permission to my wordpress site to people with a username and password?

I am using Linux Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 4):

Here we go, in form of a plugin :)

[image: custom folder file listing in wordpress]

### Notes

- The media submenu is added with the function [`add_media_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_media_page).
- The folder being read is `wp-content/custom/`, using [WordPress constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29) `WP_CONTENT_*`. If you haven't modified them, they point to the default content dir.
- Adjust the value of `$baseDir` and `$baseUrl`.
- Maybe, instead of linking directly to the file, you'd want to [force the download](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20force%20download) or open a [media player](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5Dfiletype%20media%20player).
- Create a new PHP file, paste the code, put in your plugins folder, activate

### Plugin

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: List Files in Custom Folder
Plugin URI: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13416177/1287812
Description: Add a Media page where the contents of a custom folder are listed as "<a>Filename</a> - Size"
Author: Rodolfo Buaiz
Author URI: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/12615/brasofilo
Version: 1.0
License: GPL
*/
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'so_13416177_folder_menu' );

function so_13416177_folder_menu() 
{
    add_media_page( 
        'Custom Folder Media', 
        'Custom Folder', 
        'delete_plugins', 
        'so-13416177', 
        'so_13416177_display_page' 
    );
}

function so_13416177_display_page() 
{
    $baseDir = WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/custom';
    $baseUrl = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/custom/';
    $files = array();
    
    if ( $dir = opendir( $baseDir ) ) 
    {
        while ( $file = readdir( $dir ) ) 
        {
            if ( $file != "." && $file != '..' ) 
            {
                if ( !is_dir( $baseDir . "/" . $file ) ) 
                {
                    // Hide files that start with a dot
                    if( !so_834303_starts_with( $file, '.' ) ) 
                    {
                        $size = so_13416177_file_size( 
                            filesize( $baseDir . "/" . $file ) 
                            );
                        $files[] = array( $file, $size );
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        closedir($dir);     
    }

    ?><div id="icon-upload" class="icon32"></div><h2>Custom Folder</h2><?php
    
    if ( empty( $files ) ) 
    {
        echo '<p>No files!</p>';
        break;
    }
    ?>              
    <table class="widefat">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Size</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Size</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($files as $file) 
    {
        ?>
           <tr>
              <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $baseUrl.$file[0]; ?>">
                <?php echo $file[0]; ?>
                </a>
             </td>
             <td><b><?php echo $file[1]; ?></b></td>
           </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/q/834303
function so_834303_starts_with( $haystack, $needle )
{
    return !strncmp( $haystack, $needle, strlen( $needle ) );
}

// http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#110739
function so_13416177_file_size( $o, $depth=0 ) 
{
    if( $o > 1024 ) 
        return so_13416177_file_size( $o/1024, $depth+1 );
    
    $unit = array( 'B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'PB', 'ZB', 'YB' );
    return sprintf( '%.01f %s', $o, $unit[$depth] );
}
```

---

### PS.

To give users read only capability, set their role to [`Subscriber`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Subscriber).