# Checking the characters in a string

Tags: php

I would like to see if the string `"profile.php"` ends in or the last 4 charcaters equal `".php"`

How can I do this with PHP

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) This really is easy in PHP. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/pathinfo   http://php.net/substr

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP startsWith() and endsWith() functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) to get the last 4 characters, then compare it to the string `".php"`.

```
if (substr("profile.php", -4) === ".php")
{
    echo "Ends in .php";
}
else
{
    echo "Doesn't end in .php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try PHP's inbuilt function [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n"; // return php
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n";
?>
```