# search through array of strings for fuzzy string match

Tags: php, regex, arrays, search

I have two arrays which look like the following:

```
$arr1 = ("stringType1AndSomeRandomStuff",
         "stringType2AndSomeRandomStuff",
         "stringType3AndSomeRandomStuff",
         "stringType1AndSomeRandomStuff",
         "stringType2AndSomeRandomStuff",
         "i don't belong here at all!",
         "stringType4AndSomeRandomStuff");
```

In this first array (`$arr1`), most of the keys have some sort of common attribute. In the example text above, this would be `stringTypeX`. This 'common factor' is what I need to search by. Each string also has some sort of extra data exemplified by `AndSomeRandomStuff`.

The second array looks like this:

```
$arr2 = ("stringType1" => "category1",
         "stringType2" => "category2",
         "stringType3" => "category3",
         "stringType4" => "category4");
```

I need to go through each string in `$arr1` and see if it closely matches any of the *keys* in `$arr2`. If it matches for one of the keys, I need the *value* of the *key* from `$arr2`.

How can I iterate through each of the strings in `$arr1` and determine which (if any) of the *keys* in `$arr2` apply? Basically, I need to go through every string in `$arr1` and perform a *partial* match on *all* of the keys in `$arr2`, to find the closest match. The immediate solution that comes to mind is to use two loops (outer for everything in `$arr1` and inner for each in `$arr2`), but is there a function in PHP that can take a string and see if it matches any string in an existing array?  Does anybody know of a more performant way to do this?

Comment: So, you want to make parallel comparison between each of the two array's values'?

Comment: Simon _eQ, This is **exactly** what i needed to do.  I just lacked the vocabulary >:(.  Thanks!.

Comment: It seems someone has already given an answer, so I am assuming this question is resolved?

Comment: @user1521764 -- Please do not add "SOLVED" to your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map `$arr1` to a function that calculates the string-edit-distance to the keys in `$arr2`, and then returns the closest match. Take a look at [this Levenshtein distance](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function. Or, you could simply do a [startsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions) comparison in your mapping function.

You'll likely have something that looks like this:

```
$stringEditDistanceThreshold = 5; // greater than this means rejected

// define the mapping function
function findClosestMatchingString($s) {
    $closestDistanceThusFar = $stringEditDistanceThreshold + 1;
    $closestMatchValue      = null;

    foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
        $editDistance = levenshtein($key, $s);

        // exact match
        if ($editDistance == 0) {
            return $value;

        // best match thus far, update values to compare against/return
        } elseif ($editDistance < $closestDistanceThusFar) {
            $closestDistanceThusFar = $editDistance;
            $closestMatchValue      = $value;
        }
    }

    return $closestMatch; // possible to return null if threshold hasn't been met
}

// do the mapping
$matchingValues = array_map('findClosestMatchingString', $arr1);
```

You'll likely have to tune the `$stringEditDistanceThreshold` until you get values that you're happy with. Or you could use a [startsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions) function, which would greatly simplify what `findClosestMatchingString` has to do.

Finally, this isn't very efficient. It's effectively an ugly nested loop. You may be able to do some pruning or something else clever, but I suspect if the arrays are fairly small, you may not care.

**EDIT:** As stated by @Ohgodwhy in the comment below, [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) will likely work even better for you. In that case, your map function will look something like the following:

```
function findFirstMatchingString($s) {
    $matchingKeys = preg_grep($s, array_keys($arr2));

    if (!empty($matchingKeys) {
        // return the value of the first match
        return $arr2[$matches[0]];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to `preg_grep`, then on the returned flags simply `preg_split()` and compare that to the key, and get the value?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: yep, preg_grep is likely way better. I didn't think of that. I suppose I had more of a 'fuzzy' match example in my mind.