# PHP: preg_match not working

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
$data = "Normal text
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspcode
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspcode
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspcode
Normal text";
$data = nl2br($data);
$data= explode('<br />', $data );
foreach($data as $value){
if(preg_match('/^&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp/',$value)){
echo 'code';
echo '<br />';
}else{
echo 'Not code';
echo '<br />';
}
}
```

I want to check if each of the lines starts with 4 spaces and if it does i want to echo as 'Code' and if it doesn't i want to echo as 'Not code'. But i am getting the output as 'Not code' though the 2nd , 3rd and 4th lines start with four spaces. I cannot figure out what I have done wrong. Please help me.

Comment: shouldn't there be a ';' in the end of the `&nbsp;`

Comment: Why dont you use $data = explode("\n", $data); instead of nl2br and then exploding by <br>?

Comment: ^ will only match the condition if string start with &nasp

Comment: @MightyPork I agree with you general suggestion, but would recommend use of `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` as the string to explode on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it working
added a trim() to get rid of the newline in front of the string

nl2br replace `\n` with `<br />\n` (or `<br />\r\n`),
so when spliting on `<br />` the `\n` is left as the first char

```
<?php
        $data = "Normal text
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspcode
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspcode
&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspcode
Normal text";

        $data = nl2br($data);

        $data= explode('<br />', $data );

        foreach($data as $value)
        {
                if(preg_match('/^&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp/', trim($value)))
                {
                        echo 'code';
                }
                else
                {
                        echo 'Not code';
                }
                echo '<br />';
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`nl2br` doesn't generate `<br />` unless you tell it to. Your `explode` logic is wrong.

Instead, try this:

```
$data = "Normal text.......";
foreach(explode("\n",$data) as $line) {
    // your existing foreach content code here
}
```

Comment: It would be preferable to use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\n` as the string to explode on for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Assuming that this text is coming from the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "startsWith" as defined here...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/834355/2180189

...instead of the regexp match. That is, if the spaces are always at the beginning