# REGEX - How can i check the first occurence of a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string :

```
abc:def    abc:ghi    abc:jkl
```

How can I check if my first occurence start with "abc:"? The string has no space except tabulations (\t). This is the result I need :

```
abc:def    abc:ghi    abc:jkl    // true
foo:def    abc:ghi    abc:jkl    // false
def        abc:ghi    abc:jkl    // false
abc:def    foo:ghi    jkl        // true
```

Also, i need to check the others parts if needed. For example if i need to check the 2st part :

```
abc:def    abc:ghi    abc:jkl    // true
foo:def    bar:ghi    abc:jkl    // false
def        ghi        abc:jkl    // false
foo:def    abc:ghi    jkl        // true
```

I tried `preg_match("/abc\:([^\t]+)/",$data,$match);` it's worked but this code also return `true` if the others occurences contains "abc:". Thank you!

**EDIT** : I'm sorry but this is not a duplicate question. Please see the the second part of my issue. In this second part i'm not requesting how get an element in the first occurence. [PHP startsWith() and endsWith() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions) has not the solution to this second part of my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use regex.  PHP has a lot of builtin functions that can search for you.

For first occurrence:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

```
strpos($data, 'abc') === 0
```

You can explode each line by "\t" and then check whichever ones you want with the above `strpos` function.

Comment: Oh, this is good! I think i can do someting with this. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No regex required, you can just use:

```
   (strpos($string, 'abc') === 0)
```

It will check that abc is located at the 0 index of the string. (if abc does not exist, it will return -1)

Answer (score 1):

First, get the line and explode the string so you have each column in its own bucket.

```
$line_data = preg_split("/\t/",$line);
```

Then, pick which column you want and see if it matches what you need.

```
if (preg_match("/^abc\b/",$line_data[1])){  #This matches the beginning of column 2 only if the string is on a boundary.
    #Do stuff
}
```