# Excluding folders with the word 'thumbs' in it

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, file-get-contents

I'm trying to display a list of all folders inside of a directory.  But I do not want any folders listed that contain the word "thumbs" in it.  Can someone tell me how to do this...  Here is the code I am using that doesn't seem to work.  It displays all of the folders but it is not blocking the ones with the word "thumbs" in it.

```
<?php
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('puzzle/images/puzzles/',
    FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$it  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$it->setMaxDepth(1);

foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo == '*thumbs') {
        // PLACEHOLDER
    } elseif ($fileinfo->isDir()) {
        echo $fileinfo . "<br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```

The output looks like this....

```
puzzle/images/puzzles/vehicles

puzzle/images/puzzles/vehicles/thumbs

puzzle/images/puzzles/scenery

puzzle/images/puzzles/scenery/thumbs

puzzle/images/puzzles/movies

puzzle/images/puzzles/movies/thumbs

puzzle/images/puzzles/thumbnails

puzzle/images/puzzles/holidays

puzzle/images/puzzles/holidays/thumbs

puzzle/images/puzzles/holidays/thanksgiving
```

This is what I want the output to look like except without the following folders...

```
puzzle/images/puzzles/vehicles/thumbs

puzzle/images/puzzles/scenery/thumbs

puzzle/images/puzzles/movies/thumbs

puzzle/images/puzzles/holidays/thumbs
```

Or any future folders with the name "thumbs" that I put in there later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$fileinfo == '*thumbs'` will only match the exact string `'*thumbs'`, because `==` does not recognize `*` as a wildcard.

You want to use something like this:
`strpos($fileinfo ,'thumbs') !== false`

If the filepath needs to end with `'thumbs'`, you can define an `endsWith` function*:

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === "" || substr($haystack, -strlen($needle)) === $needle;
}
```

Then call the function like so:

```
if (endswith($fileinfo, "thumbs")){

}
```

*from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473026/662761)

Comment: That works great... but what if I still want to use a folder such as puzzle/images/puzzles/scenery/thumbs/large ...(where the word thumbs is not at the end of the string)? I guess I forgot to mention that... but I just want to exclude folders paths that END in the word thumbs.

Comment: Jack - U ROCK!  Thanks!  Everything tested and works perfectly.