# php: if current url contains "/demo" do something

Tags: php, url, conditional-operator

I want to check if my  current URL contains "/demo" at the end of the url, for example `mysite.com/test/somelink/demo` to do something. 
Here is my attempt :

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'mysite.com/test/somelink/demo') 
 {
// Do something
}
else
{
// Do something
}
```

This seems to work fine, but the problem is that `/somelink` needs to by dynamic.

Any suggestion on how can I do this ?

Thank you !

**Edit:**

```
<?php
/* An abstract class for providing form types */
abstract class ECF_Field_Type {
    private static $types = array();
    protected $name;

    /* Constructor */
    public function __construct() {
        self::register_type( $this->name, $this );
    }

if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'stats'){
echo "Hello World";
}

    /* Display form field */

    public abstract function form_field( $name, $field );

    /* Display the field's content */
    public function display_field( $id, $name, $value ) {
        return "<span class='ecf-field ecf-field-$id'>"
            . "<strong class='ecf-question'>$name:</strong>"
            . " <span class='ecf-answer'>$value</span></span>\n";
    }


    /* Display field plain text suitable for email display */
    public function display_plaintext_field( $name, $value ) {
        return "$name: $value";
    }

    /* Get the description */
    abstract public function get_description();
}
?>
```

Comment: how about:`if (substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],-4) == "demo") {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use,

```
if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == 'demo'){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Just tried but I'm getting a weird syntax error : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting T_FUNCTION in`

Comment: Yes, I think is something wrong with my code but I don't understand why, I've edited my question with what I've tried please take a look...

Comment: So now what is the issue ?

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting T_FUNCTION in`

Comment: And if put it outside the `abstract class ECF_Field_Type {` is working fine

Comment: I think I will ask another question for this issue because is not related with what I was asking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if (preg_match("/\/demo$/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
?>
```

Comment: Just tried it and Im getting a weird syntax error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting T_FUNCTION in`

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/php-startswith-and-endswith-functions) has PHP code for simple startsWidth() and endsWith() functions in PHP that you could use. Your code would end up looking like:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(endsWith($host, '/demo'))
{
// Do something
}
else
{
// Do something
}
```

But one thing you might want to do in addition to that is convert $host to lowercase so the case of the URL wouldn't matter. **EDIT:** That would end up looking like this:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(endsWith(strtolower($host), '/demo'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strpos`

```
$host = 'mysite.com/test/somelink/demo';
if(strpos($host,'demo')) 
  {
// Do something 
   echo "in Demo";
}
else
{
// Do something
 echo "not in Demo";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'demo';
if (substr($url, (-1 * strlen($str))) === $str) { /**/ }
```