# Change URL Extension from given URL

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to accept a URL and change it's domain to `.com` ?

For example if a user were to submit `www.example.in`, I want to check if the URL is valid, and change that to `www.example.com`. I have built a regex checker that can check if the URL is valid, but I'm not entirely sure how to check if the given extension is valid, and then to change it to `.com`

EDIT : To be clear I am not actually going to these URL's. I am getting them submitted as user input in a form, and am simply storing them. These are functions I want to do to the URL before storing, that is all.

Edit 2 : An example to make this clearer -

```
$url = 'www.example.co.uk'
$newurl = function($url);
echo $newurl
```

which would yield the output

```
 www.example.com
```

Comment: You can do that, by .htaccessfile

But make sure you have purchased both the URL. Because any URL wich not exists and you would like to do so, will not possible.

Comment: How can .htaccess solve this?

Comment: `Redirect 301 http://www.example.in/ http://www.example.com`

Comment: You can also refer more about it from this URL

https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/htaccess_redirect

Comment: I don't think you understood my question..

Comment: What you've asked is literally not possible. There are 190+ countries and each country is having it's own domain like India has. Apart, from that there are vast possibilities for hosting sites in different domain. So, I hope you need to check or redefine the logic again...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this on the server side to replace a list of selected TLDs to be translated to .coms?

```
<?php
    $url = "www.example.in";
    $replacement_tld = "com";

    # array of all TLDs you wish to support
    $valid_tlds = array("in","co.uk");
    # possible TLD source lists
    #     http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
    #     https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List



    # from http://stackoverflow.com/a/10473026/723139
    function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
    {   
        $haystack = strtolower($haystack);
        $needle = strtolower($needle);
        return $needle === "" || substr($haystack, -strlen($needle)) === $needle;
    }
    foreach($valid_tlds as $tld){
        if(endsWith($url, $tld))
        {
            echo substr($url, 0, -strlen($tld)) . $replacement_tld . "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes this is very close to what I am looking for! Specifically, if there is a way to have a list of valid TLDs already. I was hoping there would be an inbuilt function to check if the given TLD is valid, and if yes, use string functions to convert that TLD to  `.com` and store.

Comment: Not sure if there is a canonical list especially since they can add valid TLDs in the future but perhaps you can use the following. Not ideal but will work. You would also have to ensure $tld isn't empty

`$valid_tlds_source = file_get_contents("http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt");`
`$valid_tlds = explode("\n", $valid_tlds_source);`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not entirely clear, I'm assuming you wish to make this logic on PHP part.

Here's useful function to parse such strings:

```
function parseUrl ( $url )
{
    $r = "^(?:(?P<scheme>\w+)://)?";
    $r .= "(?:(?P<login>\w+):(?P<pass>\w+)@)?";
    $r .= "(?P<host>(?:(?P<subdomain>[\w\.\-]+)\.)?" . "(?P<domain>\w+\.(?P<extension>\w+)))";
    $r .= "(?::(?P<port>\d+))?";
    $r .= "(?P<path>[\w/]*/(?P<file>\w+(?:\.\w+)?)?)?";
    $r .= "(?:\?(?P<arg>[\w=&]+))?";
    $r .= "(?:#(?P<anchor>\w+))?";
    $r = "!$r!";

    preg_match( $r, $url, $out );

    return $out;
}
```

You can parse URL, validate it, and then recreate from resulting array replacing anything you want.

If you want to practice regexp and create own patterns - [this site will be best place to do it.](http://regex101.com/#pcre)

If your goal to route users from one url to another or change URI style, then you need to use mod rewrite.

Actually in this case you will end up configuring your web server, probably virtual host, because it will route only listed domains (those being parked at the server).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty text file using a text editor such as notepad, and save it as htaccess.txt.

301 (Permanent) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different URL on a permanent basis. This is the most common type of redirect and is useful in most situations. In this example, we are redirecting to the "mt-example.com" domain:

> ```
> # This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
> Redirect 301 / http://mt-example.com/
> ```

302 (Temporary) Redirect: Point an entire site to a different temporary URL. This is useful for SEO purposes when you have a temporary landing page and plan to switch back to your main landing page at a later date:

> ```
> # This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
> Redirect 302 / http://mt-example.com/
> ```

For more details : http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F

Answer (score 0):

To validate a URL in PHP You can use **filter_var()** .

filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))

and then to get Top Level Domain **(TLD)**  and replace the it with .com , you can use following function :

```
 $url="http://www.dslreports.in";
 $ext="com";
 function change_url($url,$ext)
 {
    if(filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $tld = '';
    $url_parts = parse_url( (string) $url );
    if( is_array( $url_parts ) && isset( $url_parts[ 'host' ] ) )
      {
        $host_parts = explode( '.', $url_parts[ 'host' ] );
        if( is_array( $host_parts ) && count( $host_parts ) > 0 )
           {
          $tld = array_pop( $host_parts );
           }
       }

        $new_url=  str_replace($tld,$ext,$url);
        return $new_url;
   }else{
    return "Not a valid URl";
   }
}

 echo change_url($url,$ext);
```

Hope this helps!