# PHP - If URL contains string

Tags: php

I am trying to check with PHP if the user is on some specific pages. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/forum/"){echo "class='active'";} ?>
```

Although, this only works if the URL is `http://example.com/forum/`

How can I make the above code works, on both /forum/ but also on `/forum/??`

Example:

```
http://example.com/forum/anotherpage
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `startswith function` (see this stackoverflow post: [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top)). Here, you test would be:

```
if (startsWith ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/forum/'))
```

You can also use a regexp: http://php.net/manual/en/regex.examples.php. Here, your test would be:

```
if (preg_match ('#^/forum/#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works perfectly! (Used the preg_match solution). Question: What's the #^ before /forum/ representing)

Comment: `#` is the regexp delimiter. It can be anything (often `#` or `/`, but you need to escape this delimiter in the regexp, so `/` isn't really good there). `^` mean *begining of the string*.

Comment: I'd advice against using regex for this especially if you need to check multiple URLs it will be a performance killer compared to other solutions.

Comment: @TomToms Would you advise "startsWith"?

Comment: If you just need it for one url yes, for multiple I would use an explode().