# How do you detect if a specific word is at the end of a string in php

Tags: php

I have event listings that look like this

```
PAPA ROACH AT THE PARAMOUNT IN HUNTINGTON ON APR 28, 2015
```

Im trying to remove everything after the last "ON"

```
$s="PAPA ROACH AT THE PARAMOUNT IN HUNTINGTON ON APR 28, 2015";
echo strstr($s, 'ON', true);
```

I came up with something like this but it removes everything after the first "ON" it detects, is there a way to run this backwards or tell to skip to the last "ON"

Comment: Are they always separated by white space? If so, try ' ON ' instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php

Comment: Find the last position of a substring with [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), then use `substr()` to get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strrpos` function to perform search from the end of the string:

```
$s="PAPA ROACH ON THE PARAMOUNT IN HUNTINGTON ON APR 28, 2015";
echo substr($s, 0, strrpos($s, ' ON ') + 3); // +3 is to include the word ON
```

Comment: I think in order to get the word ON you need to search for ' ON ' including withe spaces, otherwise it will stop by the first occurrence.