# php check user provied email address that ends with specific host

Tags: php

I need to check if the email id provided by the user ends with `aa.bb.cc`

For example if the user provides an email id `name@collegename.aa.bb.cc` i want the check to only be placed on `aa.bb.cc` collegename can be whatever it does not matter but the id must end with `aa.bb.cc`

So to achieve it I tried

```
$value = 'name@collegename.aa.bb.cc';
$explodedEmail = explode('@', $value);
$domain = array_pop($explodedEmail);
```

This gives me an output of

> collegename.aa.bb.cc

So how can I place a check where the `collegename` is ignored and i have just `aa.bb.cc`

Comment: Take a look at "regular expressions" and how functions like `preg_match()` work. Read its documentation for that, it comes with good examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) (again), this time with a added limit:

```
$dot = explode('.',$domain,2);
```

Which prints out

```
Array 
( 
    [0] => collegename 
    [1] => aa.bb.cc 
)
```

And then it would be a simple matter of matching against `$dot[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "regular expressions" and how functions like preg_match() work. Read its documentation for that, it comes with good examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

A simple example would be such code:

```
<?php
$subject = 'name@collegename.aa.bb.cc';
$pattern = '/^([^@]+)@([^.]+)\.(.+)$/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens);
```

The output is:

```
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  string(25) "name@collegename.aa.bb.cc"
  [1] =>
  string(4) "name"
  [2] =>
  string(11) "collegename"
  [3] =>
  string(8) "aa.bb.cc"
}
```

To make a more specific test against the domain `aa.bb.cc` and *not* match anything else you could use a more specific regular expression:

```
$pattern = '/^([^@]+)@([^.]+)\.aa\.bb\.cc$/';
```

So regular expressions offer a very flexible tool to separate tokens inside a subject string. To develop more complex matching patterns online regex tools are available for example https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to detect this:

```
preg_match("\aa\.bb\.cc$\", $value)
```

This return true if the email ends in aa.bb.cc

If you want more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty trivial

```
 // Check if email is valid
 if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   list($user,domain) = explode('@', $email);

   if ($domain === 'yourdomain.com') {
      // here goes logic if domain is valid
   }
 }
```

There are also other options:

check if string ends with domain.com with substr() [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php)

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    // search forward starting from end minus needle length characters
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== false);
}

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   if ($endsWith($email) === 'aa.bb.cc') {
      // here goes logic if domain is valid
   }
 }
```

preg_split/preg_match to extract valid domain

But in the most cases first one will work

Comment: _"how can I place a check where the collegename is ignored and i have just aa.bb.cc"_ So anything before the `aa.bb.cc` doesn't matter.

Comment: then option with ends with will work ->     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php