# (PHP) Matching a user search to an array

Tags: php, search, levenshtein-distance

First of all, I'm new to development so need a little hand holding.

I've built a simple search field (with suggestions) and send users to a relevant landing page on an array match. I return an error message if the search isn't relevant. However, my code relies on the user clicking a suggestion or typing the whole word in the search field. Therefore, the usability is poor.

The code below will highlight my problem. Ideally, I need to match a field input 'br' to 'bristol' (as per my suggestion to the user). I think the solution is http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php but I'm having problems implementing (like I said, I'm new). I would appreciate any guidance.

Thanks heaps for your time!

```
<?php

$counties = array("Avon",
"Bristol",
"Bedfordshire",
"Berkshire",
"Buckinghamshire"
);

if (in_array(strtolower($_GET["my_input"]), array_map('strtolower', $counties)))

{ header('Location: http://domain.co.uk/county/'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $_GET['my_input'])));
}

else

{
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?message=tryagain");
exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be optimized but in general:

```
foreach(array_map('strtolower', $counties) as $county) {
    if(substr($county, 0, strlen($_GET["my_input"])) == strtolower($_GET["my_input"])) {
        header('Location: http://domain.co.uk/county/'.str_replace(' ', '-', $county));
        exit;
    }
}
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?message=tryagain");
exit;
```

- Loop the `$counties` and compare the `$_GET["my_input"]` to the same number of beginning characters in `$county`
- Make sure to use `$county` in the header and not `$_GET["my_input"]`

Obviously if the user enters `Be` then `Bedfordshire` being the first entry will be chosen.  So long as your "suggestions" are in the same order it should work fine.

In case the user enters a trailing space or something, maybe `trim()`:

```
if(substr($county, 0, strlen(trim($_GET["my_input"]))) == strtolower(trim($_GET["my_input"]))) {
```

Comment: Works perfect! The trim element appeared to break the code but I'll look into that further. Users are so used to typing a few characters that my code was falling down half the time and I was losing users. But this has done the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should get you closer (if not) to your goal:

```
if(array_key_exists('my_input', $_GET){

   $input = $_GET["my_input"];
   $counties = array("Avon", "Bristol", "Bedfordshire", "Berkshire",  "Buckinghamshire");

   // no shortest distance found, yet
   $shortest = -1;

   // loop through words to find the closest
   foreach ($counties as $country) {

      $lev = levenshtein($input, $country);

      // check for an exact match
      if ($lev == 0) {
          $closest = $country;
          $shortest = 0;
          // break out of the loop; we've found an exact match
          break;
     }

       // if this distance is less than the next found shortest
       // distance, OR if a next shortest word has not yet been found
       if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
           // set the closest match, and shortest distance
           $closest  = $country;
           $shortest = $lev;
       }
   }

    if($shortest < 5){ //insert your own value here ( accuracy )
        header('Location: http://domain.co.uk/county/'.strtolower($closest));
    }else{    
        // if not match
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?message=tryagain");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [`startsWith` function from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10473026/4233593) and iterate over your counties setting a flag if a match is found.

```
<?php

function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    // search backwards starting from haystack length characters from the end
    return $needle === "" || strrpos($haystack, $needle, -strlen($haystack)) !== false;
}

$counties = array("Avon",
"Bristol",
"Bedfordshire",
"Berkshire",
"Buckinghamshire"
);

foreach (array_map('strtolower', $counties) as $county){
  if(startsWith($county, strtolower($_GET["my_input"]))){
    header('Location: http://domain.co.uk/county/'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $_GET['my_input'])));
    $match = true;
    break;
  }
}

if(empty($match))
  header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?message=tryagain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing levenshtein for your code would look something like:

```
$counties = array(
    "Avon",
    "Bristol",
    "Bedfordshire",
    "Berkshire",
    "Buckinghamshire"
);

$input = 'Bed';
$shortest = -1;

foreach($counties as $county) {

    $lev = levenshtein($input, $county);
    var_dump($county, $lev);

    if ($lev == 0) {
        $closest = $county;
        break;
    }

    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        $closest  = $county;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }

}

echo $closest;
```

But I don't think this will do exactly what you're looking for because technically `Avon` is closer to `Bed` than `Bedfordshire` using this algorithm.

There is a [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function in PHP which might give you better results.

```
$counties = array(
    "Avon",
    "Bristol",
    "Bedfordshire",
    "Berkshire",
    "Buckinghamshire"
);

$input = 'Bed';
$mostSimilar = 0;

foreach($counties as $county) {

    similar_text($input, $county, $similarity);

    if ($similarity == 100) {
        $closest = $county;
        break;
    }

    if ($mostSimilar <= $similarity || $similarity < 0) {
        $closest  = $county;
        $mostSimilar = $similarity;
    }

}

echo $closest;
```