# regex pattern that matches the string at the end of a string but is not followed by line break

Tags: php, regex, string, line-breaks, pcre

I use a regex pattern i preg_match php function. The pattern is let's say `'/abc$/'`. It matches both strings:

```
'abc'
```

and

```
'abc
'
```

The second one has the line break at its end. What would be the pattern that matches only this first string?

```
'abc'
```

Comment: [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/834303/4577762)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why `/abc$/` matches both `"abc\n"` and `"abc"` is that `$` matches the location at the end of the string, or (even without `/m` modifier) the position before the newline that is at the end of the string.

You need the following regex:

```
/abc\z/
```

where `\z` is the unambiguous *very* end of the string, or

```
/abc$/D
```

where the `/D` modifier will make `$` behave the same way as `\z`. See [PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.anchors.php):

> The meaning of dollar can be changed so that it matches only at the very end of the string, by setting the [`PCRE_DOLLAR_ENDONLY`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) option at compile or matching time.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL5kW8/1)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.