# Match beginning of string in full words

Tags: php

I am using the startsWith() function here [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php)

But I want it to only match full words.

Currently it will match the following:

```
hi
high
hiho
```

But I want it to only match "hi", not the other two words if the input is:

```
hi there
```

Comment: use `preg_replace()`

Comment: in other words, you want to check if the `hi` word occurs as a separate word in the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match it with this regular expression: /^hi$|^hi\s|\shi\s|\shi$/

```
$test = ['hi', 'hi there', 'high', 'hiho'];
$pattern = '/^hi$|^hi\s|\shi\s|\shi$/';
$matches = [];

foreach ($test as $t) {
    var_dump($t);
    preg_match($pattern, $t, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Parts explained:

- ^hi$ - your sting is "hi"
- ^hi\s - your string starts with hi: "hi "
- \shi\s - there's a " hi " somewhere in your string
- \shi$ - your string ends with " hi"

Those parts are glued together with pipe "|", which in regex means "or", so the entire expression is matching any one of the parts

Comment: I used pattern '/^hi$|^hi\s/' but it does not match 'hi' and 'hi there' which it should in that case?

Answer (score 0):

If you test whole text against `hi` words, try this:

```
<?php    
preg_match_all('@hi\s@i',
        "hi me
        hi there
        high
        highlander
        historic
        hire", 
$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

[image]

Test it - modify here: https://regex101.com/r/tV3jR6/1