# If statement in foreach loop char check

Tags: php, regex, foreach

I need to only run the foreach on iterations that find a currency symbol. Currently, I have this -

```
$transferid = $key;
$donation1 = $value["news"];
$donationcomma = getStringBetween($donation1,$from,$to);
$donation = str_replace(',', '', $donationcomma);
$playeridregex = preg_match("/XID=(.*)\"/", $donation1, $playerid);
$playerid1 = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9'-]/","",$playerid[1]);
```

which I can in turn get the player ID from the string

```
<a href = "http://www..com/.php?XID=1826888">saeed</a> donated $800,000,000 to the faction
```

However, as it stands, I need to only check strings that include the money donation, $800,000,000.

Included in the output can be such things as

```
 <a href = "http://www..com/.php?XID=2023426">French_</a> donated 1 x First Aid Kit to the faction
```

I need to not run the foreach info on strings such as this.

Comment: [_**Don't use RegEx, use an XML Parser.**_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/510036)

Comment: The issue is not regex. I need to run an if statement within the foreach to check if the line has a $ symbol, otherwise don't run the foreach on it.

Comment: @saeed, why don't you use a regexp like \^\$(.+)\ to check if a string starts with a $ or simply the php function $string.startsWith('$'); and continue your operation with the results ?

Comment: If you just need to check if the string contains a `$`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php.

Comment: To solve this problem you need to learn and use XPath. Use the keyword "donated" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i understand, you could do something like this :

```
<?php
foreach($values AS $key=>$value) {
    if(preg_match('/^(\$)(.+)/', $value) == 1) { 
        $transferid = $key;
        $donation1 = $value["news"];
        $donationcomma = getStringBetween($donation1,$from,$to);
        $donation = str_replace(',', '', $donationcomma);
        $playeridregex = preg_match("/XID=(.*)\"/", $donation1, $playerid);
        $playerid1 = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9'-]/","",$playerid[1]);
    }
}
```

But still, i'm not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: What is `startWith`? Are you referencing this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/a/834355/4333555?

Comment: I was referring to the actual php startwith function but it appears that this post is about it yes.

Comment: There is no `startWith` PHP function, unless you define it.http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=startWith&scope=quickref `startwith doesn't exist.` If it did you'd probably pass `$value` to it, not concatenate it.