# Wordpress, Dynamic 404.php title based on url request

Tags: wordpress, url

I'm trying to make a dynamic title for my `404.php` error page based on the current url request.

**Typical URL request**

> ```
> https://URL/topic/4433-app-epic-reader-dla-s8500-s8530?page-3434708
> ```

**Output**

> ```
> 4433 app epic reader dla s8500
> ```

Would anybody know a plugin that could be used for that ? If not, could anyone please help me with this issue ? I have tried but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Are parameters really important ? Or is it just the page that get you a 404 ?

Comment: @amarinediary, not at all important. I want text, we can skip those numbers (this is just code formatting in stackoverflow post editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- We get the associated request with [`$_SERVER\['REQUEST_URI'\]`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).
- We clean it up to remove any parameters (anything starting from `?`).
- Case handling end of request with or without `/`.
- Make a array out of the request by splitting it at each slashes `/`.
- Pop out the last value of the array which is our requested page and to some more cleaning to remove any dashes.
- Call on the front end with `wpso66851700()`.

In your `function.php`:

```
<?php 
add_action( 'init', 'wpso66851700' );
function wpso66851700() {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if ( str_contains( $request, '?' ) ) {
            $cleaner = substr( $request, 0, strpos( $request, '?' ) );
            $request = $cleaner;
        };
        if ( str_ends_with( $request, '/' ) ) {
            $worker = explode( '/', substr( $request, 1, -1 ) );
        } else {
            $worker = explode( '/', substr( $request, 1 ) );
        };
        return ucfirst( urldecode( str_replace( '-', ' ', array_pop( $worker ) ) ) );  
    };
};
?>
```

On the front end:

```html
<!-- ... one-liner output-->
<?= wpso66851700(); ?>
<!-- ... one-liner output in a <title> tag-->
<title><?= wpso66851700(); ?></title>
<!-- ... one-liner output in a <h1> tag, with a sentence around it-->
<h1>The "<?= wpso66851700(); ?>" page got lost at sea  and is now swimming with the fishes  !</h1>
```

`<?=` means `echo`. the `is_404()` condition is passed in the function, no need to repeat it.

As per your example the output should look like:

> The "4433 app epic reader dla s8500" page got lost at sea  and is now swimming with the fishes  !

> PHP > `8.0` required due to [`str_contains()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) and [`str_ends_with()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php).

---

### PHP < 8.0, [`str_contains()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) and [`str_ends_with()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php) alternative

```
<?php
function endsWith( $needle, $haystack ) { //... @credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/834355/3645650
    $length = strlen( $needle );
    if( ! $length ) {
        return true;
    };
    return substr( $haystack, -$length ) === $needle;
};

add_action( 'init', 'wpso66851700' );
function wpso66851700() {
    if ( is_404() ) {
        $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if ( strpos( $request, '?' ) !== false ) {
            $cleaner = substr( $request, 0, strpos( $request, '?' ) );
            $request = $cleaner;
        };
        if ( endsWith( '/', $request ) ) {
            $worker = explode( '/', substr( $request, 1, -1 ) );
        } else {
            $worker = explode( '/', substr( $request, 1 ) );
        };
        return ucfirst( urldecode( str_replace( '-', ' ', array_pop( $worker ) ) ) );  
    };
};
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, but I want it to be dynamic (I mean those are just the examples of url syntax in different versions - url is different for topic, different for forum, different for profile).

Sorry for misunderstanding...

Comment: I have a small request on top - how to implement this to use it for page title (the one between <title></title> tags)? I mean probably "if" and "else", but hell with my php knowledge... :/

Comment: I want to put output of this in the page title. If page is 404, the title should be as well the same (the exploded url) and not "404 page not found".

Anyway, I have to debug your code as it gives no output at all...

Comment: mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_contains() in

I guess it's time for php 8.0...

Comment: Any chance for function without php 8.0's str_contains? It seems that my server does not have and I need to put it offline for like 3 hours to make it work (which is impossible because of other things I got there).

Comment: Now it's: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_ends_with() in wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php:939

Comment: A now it does not give an error, but it gives BLANK output. Nothing there.

Comment: Wait. ECHO. Ok, works :) Thank you very much!

Comment: I added an update in the question - should i start new topic? Is it doable at all or it's far more complicated?

Comment: I have another problem, that I did not expect. Not of all urls end with "?page", some of them end with forward slash "/". Could you please help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230586/discussion-between-amarinediary-and-spinecki).