# Downloadscript > Do not display files with a specific extension

Tags: php, file, download

Donloadscript > Do not display files with a specific extension.

I have a script for downloads in which the following instruction does not show certain files. This also works very well.

```
while ($file_name = readdir($dir_handle)) {
        // Hide files so only visible files can be downloaded
        if ($file_name != '.access' and $file_name != '.' and $file_name != '.htaccess' and $file_name != 'index.php' and $file_name != '001.php' and $file_name != '002.php' and $file_name != '003.php' and $file_name != '005.php' and $file_name != '007.php' and $file_name != '009.php' and $file_name != '010.php') {
$show_files
}
```

Question:
How to define all PHP files globally instead of having to explicitly define each PHP file like in the posted code? It doesn't work with `$file_name != '*.php`

Many thanks in advance for tips and hints

Comment: Put them in an array and use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP 8 we have `str_ends_with` which should work for you. That, along with a lookup array for literal files should be enough. See this for a version of [`str_ends_with`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834355/231316) for older versions of PHP, although I’d recommend the [Symfony polyfill](https://github.com/symfony/polyfill) potentially, too, just to have access to other functions.

```php
function shouldFileBeHiddenA(string $file): bool {
    static $knownHiddenFiles = ['.access', '.', '.htaccess'];
    
    if(in_array($file, $knownHiddenFiles)) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if(str_ends_with($file, '.php')) {
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

An alternative is to use the `pathinfo` function which is probably overkill but might read easier for some people:

```php
function shouldFileBeHiddenB(string $file): bool {
    static $knownHiddenFiles = ['.access', '.', '.htaccess'];
    static $knownHiddenExtensions = ['php'];
    
    if(in_array($file, $knownHiddenFiles)) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if(in_array(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $knownHiddenExtensions)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/HiJHe

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer until today due to health reasons. Many thanks for the help