# How to do Street Number validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate street number. I want to allow user to input "/" and "-"
how can I do it with codeigniter forn validation.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('StreetNo', 'Street No', 'required|alpha_numeric');
```

The above code is the that I'm using at the moment. Could guys please help me with
this?

Comment: do your *really* need to do this;  as some street numbers use other characters.

Comment: Find solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982529/form-validation-rules-for-regex-match). And feel free to use [sof|google] search function.

Comment: Like @Dagon suggested, this  isgenerally not a good idea. You will probably end up alienating people.

Comment: @Dagon but some street addresses in Australia uses like this "24/2" so I want them to type only "/"and numbers.

Comment: I think what Dagon is getting at, is just leave it at 'required' and call it a day. Don't restrict too heavily if you don't have to.

Comment: Exactly. It's going to get very complex if you want to introduce locale. I.e., if Australia is allowed a /, what about other countries that this isn't valid?

Comment: Oh I get it now.... How stupid I'm am to think only about Australia... thanks guys and @Tpojka your answer is also really helpful for me in the future