# CodeIgniter Form Validation for Chinese Words

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, validation, non-english

I am using library of Form Validation in CodeIgniter.  Below config try to include all Number, English words, Chinese words and space.  But it's not work.

```
$config = array(
                array(
                       'field' => 'keywords',
                       'label' => 'keywords',
                       'rules' => 'regex_match[/[a-zA-Z0-9 \u4e00-\u9fa5]+$/]'
                    )
                );
```

However, if I deduce '\u4e00-\u9fa5', it's work.

```
$config = array(
                    array(
                           'field' => 'keywords',
                           'label' => 'keywords',
                           'rules' => 'regex_match[/[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/]'
                        )
                    );
```

Comment: Try `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{Han}]+$/`, as in PCRE, you can match Chinese chars with `\p{Han}` Unicode property.

Comment: I test it. It can validate English words and space. But Chinese word is not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues in the regex you have:

- The validation regex should start matching at the start of the string, thus, you need the start of string anchor `^` or `\A`. Also, it is advisable to replace `$` with the very end of the string anchor `\z` (as `$` also matches before the final newline symbol in a string).
- Revo is right, `\uXXXX` notation is not supported by PHP regex engine. However, you do not have to specify the range of Unicode code points here. **Chinese characters in PHP PCRE regex [can be defined with a Unicode property `\p{Han}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923410/3832970)**.
- For a PCRE regex to become Unicode aware, you need to use the `/u` modifier.

So, use

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{Han}]+\z/u
```

Or (a tiny bit less secure),

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{Han}]+$/u
```

Comment: I test two methods.  Both method can validate English words and space. But Chinese word is not work.

Comment: Please provide a sample input string. it [matches Chinese words](https://regex101.com/r/bC2iK2/1).

Comment: I'm not sure about OP, but `\p{Han}` includes a lot more characters than the range provided. E.g. `\x{3400}-\x{4dbf}` (CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A)

Comment: To: revo
What is good for Traditional Chinese words

To: Wiktor Stribiżew
It is ok in the online test website, but not work in my code.

Comment: I forgot about the `/u` modifier. Try `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\p{Han}]+$/u`.

Comment: If this won't work, you will need to implement a callback like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982529/form-validation-rules-for-regex-match).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew.  It's work now.

And I search the difference between \p{Han} and \x{3400}-\x{4dbf} by Google.  I am not very sure, but I think they are same.

If anybody find the difference, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: It is possible Han includes more than one range. See [this PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/mbstring/php_unicode.h#L187).

Comment: @IvanK: If it works, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

PCRE does not support the `\uFFFF` syntax. Use `\x{FFFF}` instead.

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9 \x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+$/
```

Comment: I test it. it can't validate Chinese words, English words and space.

Comment: @IvanK  Giving Wiktor's sample, this RegEx [should work](https://regex101.com/r/bC2iK2/2).

Comment: It is ok in the online test website, but not work in my code.

Comment: @IvanK It's possible to use `u` modifier here as well: `/[a-zA-Z0-9 \x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+$/u`