# Substring Compare PHP

Tags: php, string, compare, substring, string-comparison

Why does this code not echo `0`?

```
$email = "test@example.com";
$ending = "com";

$email = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $email);

echo substr_compare($email, $ending, strlen($ending)-strlen($email), strlen($ending));
```

I am expecting 0, per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-compare.php).

Comment: `strlen($ending)-strlen($email)` Write that down with your example and put in the real numbers and do the math and see what offset you get and where you start the comparison.

Comment: @Rizier123 D'oh! `-11`, I guess I need to just do `-strlen($ending)`

Comment: Sometimes when you have a small code example it helps when you write it down and put in the real numbers/values.

Comment: @num8er It might be similar, since it shows another way to do it, but I think OP asks here why he got not 0 as output in his specific example.

Comment: @Rizier123 author wants to compare that it ends with "com". See title: "Substring Compare PHP". And wants to debug the result by doing echo. I thing var_dump() will return expected result.

Comment: @Rizier123 Does that mean this answer is wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/a/619725/2379592

Answer (score 0):

If You want to check if it ends with "com".

Read this: [startsWith() and endsWith() functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834303/startswith-and-endswith-functions-in-php)

But if You just want to debug the result:

Try to convert integer to string to properly output result.

```
echo (string)substr_compare($email, $ending, strlen($ending)-strlen($email), strlen($ending));
```

or do:

```
$result = substr_compare($email, $ending, strlen($ending)-strlen($email), strlen($ending));
var_dump($result); // or echo (string)$result;
```